# Javascript: What's more efficient, IF block or TRY/CATCH?

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I'd love some other opinions on what's more efficient in this code. Basically in the following code, there's a setInterval loop and I need 4 requirements to be true before the code runs in the loop. So in v.1 I wrote an if statement checking all 4. Worked fine.

Then I switched to just using try/catch, with the code I want to execute sitting in try{}. The logic was that during each loop, an exception would be generated but suppressed for each invalid condition. On the final loop where all conditions are true, the code executes and clears the interval.

Either works. I like the try/catch method because there's less conditional code that I need to write and worry about breaking. But I'm worried that try/catch is really inefficient, especially in a setInterval() loop hitting at 100ms. What are some opinions of other bright minds here on SO?

**Try/Catch**

```
var intvar = setInterval(function(){
try{    
    clearInterval(intvar);

    jQuery('#'+nav[pageid].t1+'>a').replaceWith(jQuery('<span>'+jQuery('#'+nav[pageid].t1+'>a').text()+'</span>'));

    //set display classes for nav
    jQuery('#'+nav[pageid].t1).addClass('selected').find('#'+nav[pageid].t2).addClass('subselect'); //topnav
    jQuery('#'+nav[pageid].t3).addClass('selected').find('#'+nav[pageid].t4).addClass('subselect'); //leftnav
}catch(err){}
},100);
```

**IF Block**

```
var intvar = setInterval(function(){

if(typeof jQuery == 'function' && typeof nav == 'object' && typeof pageid != 'undefined' && typeof document.getElementById('leftnav') == 'object'){
    clearInterval(intvar);
    jQuery('#'+nav[pageid].t1+'>a').replaceWith(jQuery('<span>'+jQuery('#'+nav[pageid].t1+'>a').text()+'</span>'));

    //set display classes for nav
    jQuery('#'+nav[pageid].t1).addClass('selected').find('#'+nav[pageid].t2).addClass('subselect'); //topnav
    jQuery('#'+nav[pageid].t3).addClass('selected').find('#'+nav[pageid].t4).addClass('subselect'); //leftnav
}

},100);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the if statement.  I don't know what the overhead is for a TRY/CATCH, but I suspect it's far greater than evaluating a boolean expression.  To hit the TRY/CATCH you will have to:  execute a statement, generate an error [with that associated overhead], log the error (presumably), made a stacktrace(presumably), and moved back into the code.  Additionally, if you have to debug code near those lines the real error could get obfuscated with what you are TRY/CATCHing.

Furthermore, it's a misuse of TRY/CATCH and can make your code that much harder to read.  Suppose you do this for longer or more obfuscated cases?  Where might your catch end up?

This is referred to as [Exception handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling)

EDIT:  As commented below, you only take the runtime performance hit if you actually cause an exception.

Comment: Just to add to this, the cost of the try/catch is when an exception is thrown, otherwise it's insignificant. Hence if you can reliably test for the condition (and avoid the exception) with an if it's more performant.

Comment: I don't know about JavaScript, but as far as I know a try block pushes some things on the stack. A try block inside a tight loop would make it much slower than a try block outside the loop. Is it anyhow different in JavaScript?

Answer (score 21):

Exceptions should be used for exceptional circumstances (i.e. things that you don't expect to happen normally).  You should not, in general, use exceptions to catch something that you can test for with an if statement.

Also, from what I understand, exceptions are much more expensive than if statements.

Comment: Completely disagree with this rather bold statement. E.g. in Python [`try except` is preferred](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835756/using-try-vs-if-in-python) Also, to say that something is "expensive" some data would be nice. Again, in Python ["if" is more "expensive"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3929887/1167879).

Comment: Of course, the OP was asking about Javascript, not Python. Also, you might want to read the link you provided. It says essentially the same thing as cdmckay did: Use exceptions for exceptional conditions.

Comment: @AlexOkrushko The EAFP philosophy, Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission, is adopted by the Python community not js.

Answer (score 12):

The other answers are correct, `try/catch` is for exceptional circumstances and error handling.  `if` conditions are for program logic.  "Which is faster?" is the wrong question.

A good rule of thumb, if you're doing nothing with the exception, it's probably not an exception!

To figure out which to use, let's break down your if condition.

1. `typeof jQuery == 'function'`  Is the jQuery() function defined?
2. `typeof nav == 'object'`       Does the nav global variable contain an object?
3. `typeof pageid != 'undefined'` Is the pageid global variable defined?
4. `typeof document.getElementById('leftnav') == 'object'`  Does the document contain a leftnav element?

The first is clearly an exception.  You ain't getting far without a jQuery() function.

The second is also an exception.  You're not going anywhere without a nav object.

The third is an exception.  You need a pageid to do anything.

The fourth is probably logic.  "Only run this code if there is a leftnav element".  It's hard to tell because the rest of the code doesn't reference a leftnav element!  Only the comments do, a red flag.  So it's probably a programming mistake.

So I'd probably do this (with apologies if I'm butchering jQuery):

```
var intvar = setInterval(function() {
    // If there's no leftnav element, don't do anything.
    if( typeof document.getElementById('leftnav') != 'object') {
        return;
    }

    try {
        clearInterval(intvar);
        jQuery('#'+nav[pageid].t1+'>a')
            .replaceWith(jQuery('<span>'+jQuery('#'+nav[pageid].t1+'>a').text()+'</span>'));

        //set display classes for nav
        jQuery('#'+nav[pageid].t1)
            .addClass('selected')
            .find('#'+nav[pageid].t2)
            .addClass('subselect');     //topnav
        jQuery('#'+nav[pageid].t3)
            .addClass('selected')
            .find('#'+nav[pageid].t4)
            .addClass('subselect');     //leftnav
    }
    catch(err) {
        ...do something with the error...
    }
},100);
```

...but I'd really examine if the leftnav element check is applicable.

Finally, I can't help but comment that this "function" is working with global variables.  You should instead be passing `nav` and `pageid` into the function in order to maintain encapsulation and your sanity.

Answer (score 3):

I would write the following code:

```
var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
for (var i=0; i < 1000; ++i) intvar();
var endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
alert("Took " + ((endTime - startTime) / 1000.0) " seconds");
```

Then I would try both versions of intvar and see which runs more quickly. I'd do this myself but I don't have the page layout you do so my code wouldn't work.

Some stylistic comments - it doesn't seem necessary to test that `jQuery` is a function. If it isn't, your webpage is likely messed up such that not running the `intvar` code will not help you. If you rarely expect the exceptions to be thrown, I'd use the try/catch.

Answer (score 2):

For the provided example where you are wrapping a try/catch around a block of code that should always run anyway (unless if something horrible happens), it is good form to use try/catch.  An analogy for you: do you always test "Is the sky Blue?" in your if statement, or would you wrap it in a try/catch that is triggered only when the sky happens to turn Green.

Use the If statement method if you are dealing with user provided input or if the chances of a function not existing is much higher due to something else happening in the code.

Keep in mind that if you don't trigger the exception you don't have any unwinding or backtracking across code.  In the example the catch will only execute if something is wrong (jQuery is missing or some such thing), however the if statement method has an evaluation happening on EVERY SINGLE CALL to that function - you shouldn't do more work than you have to.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer the question, as everyone else has, the try..catch is likely going to be more expensive if there actually is an error.

To point out some additional errors in the code beyond what others have already pointed out:

These two codes are not at all equivalent.  To explain, even though the codes appear to do the exact same thing, they do not.

In the case of the if() check, NONE of the code is executed.  In the case of the exception handler, each line of code inside the exception handler will be executed.  SO, what happens if the error occurs in the second, or the third line?  Then you've got something completely different happening in your code than what you get if you check the conditions before executing any of it.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the answers given, I want to add some thoughts on this subject.

Exceptions that are unforeseen, i.e. the runtime throws an exception, should not be caught with try ... catch because you want to read the message that is thrown in the console.

Try ... catch should IMO be thrown when an exception occurs that your application can foresee in your application logic and you want to perform some custom actions when they do. I.e. you want to be descriptive about it being an exception, and it's not part of the happy flow of the application logic.

For example, you could have a method that validates user input so you could have an `isValid` method that returns a boolean in which case you would use if ... then.

On the other hand if your performing a certain process, and you know that a certain exception can occur that interrupts the happy flow and you want to handle this, I feel that it is better to throw an exception.

As abstract example, you could have methods that implements some business rules.
Instead of validating every business rule for validity, you could have one custom Exception containing dynamic metadata that can be thrown by each of these methods when validity is breached and handle them appropriately, and continue the happy flow otherwise.
This would translate into something like:

```
throw new BusinessValidationException(TAG, 'Reason for the validation');
```

Which IMO is much more descriptive than:

```
if (!checkValidityBusinessRule()) 
    // doSomething
```

For a series of business rules.

As for the example, it's my humble opinion that this check shouldn't be happening in the first place and that the given checks are true by default for implementing the method.

```
if(typeof jQuery == 'function' && typeof nav == 'object' && typeof pageid != 'undefined' && typeof document.getElementById('leftnav') == 'object')
```

What it means is that you must declaratively ensure that given conditions are true before invoking the given method with side-effects, taking away the necessity to perform the checks at all.
If it so happens that one of the conditions is false, then it will throw an exception to the console, which is actually what you want because as a developer it means that something in your application logic or lifecycle is broken.

My 2 cents, I hope they make sense.