# In Python, how do I determine if an object is iterable?

Tags: python, iterable

Is there a method like `isiterable`? The only solution I have found so far is to call

```
hasattr(myObj, '__iter__')
```

But I am not sure how fool-proof this is.

Comment: `__getitem__` is also sufficient to make an object iterable

Comment: FWIW: `iter(myObj)` succeeds if `isinstance(myObj, dict)`, so if you're looking at a `myObj` that could be a sequence of `dict`s or a single `dict`, you'll succeed in both cases. A subtlety that is important if you want to know what's a sequence and what isn't. (in Python 2)

Comment: `__getitem__` is also sufficient to make an object iterable ... **if it starts at zero index**.

Comment: `__getitem__` is sufficient but not necessary. E.g. a generator object is iterable but it does not have the `__getitem__`.

Answer (score 1056, accepted):

1. Checking for `__iter__` works on sequence types, but it would fail on e.g. strings **in Python 2**. I would like to know the right answer too, until then, here is one possibility (which would work on strings, too):

   ```
   try:
       some_object_iterator = iter(some_object)
   except TypeError as te:
       print(some_object, 'is not iterable')
   ```

   The `iter` built-in checks for the `__iter__` method or in the case of strings the `__getitem__` method.
2. Another general pythonic approach is to assume an iterable, then fail gracefully if it does not work on the given object. The Python glossary:

   > Pythonic programming style that determines an object's type by inspection of its method or attribute signature rather than by explicit relationship to some type object ("If it looks like a **duck** and quacks like a **duck**, it must be a **duck**.") By emphasizing interfaces rather than specific types, well-designed code improves its flexibility by allowing polymorphic substitution. Duck-typing avoids tests using type() or isinstance(). **Instead, it typically employs the EAFP (Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission) style of programming.**
   >
   > ...
   >
   > ```
   > try:
   >    _ = (e for e in my_object)
   > except TypeError:
   >    print(my_object, 'is not iterable')
   > ```
3. The [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) module provides some abstract base classes, which allow to ask classes or instances if they provide particular functionality, for example:

   ```
   from collections.abc import Iterable

   if isinstance(e, Iterable):
       # e is iterable
   ```

   However, this does not check for classes that are iterable through `__getitem__`.

Comment: `[e for e in my_object]` can raise an exception for other reasons, ie `my_object` is undefined or possible bugs in `my_object` implementation.

Comment: A string *is* a sequence (`isinstance('', Sequence) == True`) *and* as any sequence it *is* iterable (`isinstance('', Iterable)`). Though `hasattr('', '__iter__') == False` and it might be confusing.

Comment: If `my_object` is very large (say, infinite like `itertools.count()`) your list comprehension will take up a lot of time/memory. Better to make a generator, which will never try to build a (potentially infinite) list.

Comment: What if *some_object* throws TypeError caused by other reason(bugs etc.) too? How can we tell it from the "Not iterable TypeError"?

Comment: You can look at the error message: except TypeError as e: if "is not iterable" in e: print my_object, 'is not iterable'; else: raise

Comment: @Shaung This remark was already made by Nick in the first comment.

Comment: Another case where isinstance falls down is for some C++ iterable classes

Comment: @JeremyCowles: could you elaborate? is there no way to connect to C++ classes in such a way that they behave "correctly" with `isinstance(e, Iterable)`? And why do you say it's "another case"? Do you mean old-style classes?

Comment: @max Adding check for `TypeError` doesn't solve the problem described by Nick thus Shaung's comment in a sense just reiterates Nick's comment. Checking description of an exception as Arne's suggested is always a bad idea as this description is implementation detail.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost Yes, you're right. `TypeError` may be raised from deeper layers, and an exception message may change in the next version. I guess that's why I only feel comfortable with EAFP approach when the behavior I desire is the same regardless of what caused the exception.

Comment: @ChrisLutz, changed the list comprehension to a generator expression, that should at least help performance.

Comment: Note that in Python 3: `hasattr(u"hello", '__iter__')` returns `True`

Comment: An interesting test case: `class X(object): __iter__ = 1`. 3 actually doesn't work with this.

Comment: @Stiivi *Custom classes which implement `__iter__` are automatically subclasses of `collections.Iterable`* Could you please provide reference for this statement?

Comment: only iterables have a `len()` right? so wouldn't a simple `try: l = len(myObj)` be enough to determine if `myObj` is an iterable?

Comment: A side effect of checking if an object is iterable by iterating on it as per 2. is that you will consume the first item of a generator/iterator which can have some undesirable consequences.

Comment: (2) is just a horrible and unintuitive version of (1). I actually didn't expect that to work correctly until I tried it. It's not obvious that creating a generator will immediately throw an exception if the object isn't iterable. I think the answer would be better if that was removed.

Comment: `xrange` is one object which has no `__iter__` method and is not a sequence, yet it is iterable.

Comment: @KelSolaar has already pointed out that consuming an element can have side effects, but even trying to call iter() on an object is bad, as it can be an expensive operation. For example, in Pytorch, constructing an iterator over a DataLoader involves spawning a multitude of loading processes.

Comment: @Carlos Why wouldn't it? A unicode string is perfectly iterable, right?

Comment: There is another case. Take an object that you want to provide a `__getitem__` for, but you do not want to allow iteration. To force this, you can implement `__iter__`, but an error. In this case, `isinstance(x, Iterable)` will actually cause a false positive. This may seem academic, but in PySpark, there is a `Column` object implemented in exactly this way.

Answer (score 712):

### Duck typing

```
try:
    iterator = iter(the_element)
except TypeError:
    # not iterable
else:
    # iterable

# for obj in iterator:
#     pass
```

### Type checking

Use the [Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/library/abc.html). They need at least Python 2.6 and work only for new-style classes.

```
from collections.abc import Iterable   # import directly from collections for Python < 3.3

if isinstance(the_element, Iterable):
    # iterable
else:
    # not iterable
```

However, `iter()` is a bit more reliable as described [by the documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable):

> Checking `isinstance(obj, Iterable)` detects classes that are
> registered as Iterable or that have an `__iter__()` method, but
> it does not detect classes that iterate with the `__getitem__()`
> method. The only reliable way to determine whether an object
> is iterable is to call `iter(obj)`.

Comment: From "Fluent Python" by Luciano Ramalho:

As of Python 3.4, the most accurate way to check whether an object x is iterable is to call iter(x) and handle a TypeError exception if it isn’t. This is more accurate than using isinstance(x, abc.Iterable), because iter(x) also considers the legacy __getitem__ method, while the Iterable ABC does not.

Comment: In case you're thinking "oh I'll just `isinstance(x, (collections.Iterable, collections.Sequence))` instead of `iter(x)`", note that this still won't detect an iterable object that implements only `__getitem__` but not `__len__`.  Use `iter(x)` and catch the exception.

Comment: Your second answer doesn't work. In PyUNO if I do `iter(slide1)`, all goes well, however the `isinstance(slide1, Iterable)` throws `TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class`.

Comment: @Hi-Angel sounds like a bug in `PyUNO` Notice that your error message says `issubclass()` instead of `isinstance()`.

Comment: @GeorgSchölly well, although it's sad that PyUNO is not as good as it could be *(it certainly has problems, e.g. not exposing classes of exceptions; even, almost none of existing classes)*, however what this says to me is that `isinstance()` is unreliable. You can't take a random python library, and be sure that it doesn't have a "bug" too.

Comment: Calling iter() over an object can be an expensive operation (see DataLoader in Pytorch, which forks/spawns multiple processes on iter()).

Comment: It seems that *enumerate()* has the same effect as iter() (Python 3), which may simplify things a bit if the next thing you want to do is enumerating the sequence - no need for explicit iter() beforehand, as enumerate() will raise an appropriate exception by itself if necessary.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I suspect iterating the object could be problematic (ie. pure vs impure actions) for instance -- I wouldn't want to iterate a generator to see if it's iterable

Comment: @szali that's really just bad design on PyTorch's side then.

Comment: @MarcinWojnarski well, *anything* that does iteration will eventually raise that error

Answer (score 227):

I'd like to shed a little bit more light on the interplay of `iter`, `__iter__` and `__getitem__` and what happens behind the curtains. Armed with that knowledge, you will be able to understand why the best you can do is

```
try:
    iter(maybe_iterable)
    print('iteration will probably work')
except TypeError:
    print('not iterable')
```

I will list the facts first and then follow up with a quick reminder of what happens when you employ a `for` loop in python, followed by a discussion to illustrate the facts.

## Facts

1. You can get an iterator from any object `o` by calling `iter(o)` if at least one of the following conditions holds true: 
   a) `o` has an `__iter__` method which returns an iterator object. An iterator is any object with an `__iter__` and a `__next__` (Python 2: `next`) method. 
   b) `o` has a `__getitem__` method.
2. Checking for an instance of `Iterable` or `Sequence`, or checking for the
   attribute `__iter__` is not enough.
3. If an object `o` implements only `__getitem__`, but not `__iter__`, `iter(o)` will construct
   an iterator that tries to fetch items from `o` by integer index, starting at index 0. The iterator will catch any `IndexError` (but no other errors) that is raised and then raises `StopIteration` itself.
4. In the most general sense, there's no way to check whether the iterator returned by `iter` is sane other than to try it out.
5. If an object `o` implements `__iter__`, the `iter` function will make sure
   that the object returned by `__iter__` is an iterator. There is no sanity check
   if an object only implements `__getitem__`.
6. `__iter__` wins. If an object `o` implements both `__iter__` and `__getitem__`, `iter(o)` will call `__iter__`.
7. If you want to make your own objects iterable, always implement the `__iter__` method.

## `for` loops

In order to follow along, you need an understanding of what happens when you employ a `for` loop in Python. Feel free to skip right to the next section if you already know.

When you use `for item in o` for some iterable object `o`, Python calls `iter(o)` and expects an iterator object as the return value. An iterator is any object which implements a `__next__` (or `next` in Python 2) method and an `__iter__` method.

By convention, the `__iter__` method of an iterator should return the object itself (i.e. `return self`). Python then calls `next` on the iterator until `StopIteration` is raised. All of this happens implicitly, but the following demonstration makes it visible:

```
import random

class DemoIterable(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        print('__iter__ called')
        return DemoIterator()

class DemoIterator(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        print('__next__ called')
        r = random.randint(1, 10)
        if r == 5:
            print('raising StopIteration')
            raise StopIteration
        return r
```

Iteration over a `DemoIterable`:

```
>>> di = DemoIterable()
>>> for x in di:
...     print(x)
...
__iter__ called
__next__ called
9
__next__ called
8
__next__ called
10
__next__ called
3
__next__ called
10
__next__ called
raising StopIteration
```

## Discussion and illustrations

**On point 1 and 2: getting an iterator and unreliable checks**

Consider the following class:

```
class BasicIterable(object):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if item == 3:
            raise IndexError
        return item
```

Calling `iter` with an instance of `BasicIterable` will return an iterator without any problems because `BasicIterable` implements `__getitem__`.

```
>>> b = BasicIterable()
>>> iter(b)
<iterator object at 0x7f1ab216e320>
```

However, it is important to note that `b` does not have the `__iter__` attribute and is not considered an instance of `Iterable` or `Sequence`:

```
>>> from collections import Iterable, Sequence
>>> hasattr(b, '__iter__')
False
>>> isinstance(b, Iterable)
False
>>> isinstance(b, Sequence)
False
```

This is why [Fluent Python](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032519.do) by Luciano Ramalho recommends calling `iter` and handling the potential `TypeError` as the most accurate way to check whether an object is iterable. Quoting directly from the book:

> As of Python 3.4, the most accurate way to check whether an object `x` is iterable is to call `iter(x)` and handle a `TypeError` exception if it isn’t. This is more accurate than using `isinstance(x, abc.Iterable)` , because `iter(x)` also considers the legacy `__getitem__` method, while the `Iterable` ABC does not.

**On point 3: Iterating over objects which only provide `__getitem__`, but not `__iter__`**

Iterating over an instance of `BasicIterable` works as expected: Python
constructs an iterator that tries to fetch items by index, starting at zero, until an `IndexError` is raised. The demo object's `__getitem__` method simply returns the `item` which was supplied as the argument to `__getitem__(self, item)` by the iterator returned by `iter`.

```
>>> b = BasicIterable()
>>> it = iter(b)
>>> next(it)
0
>>> next(it)
1
>>> next(it)
2
>>> next(it)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Note that the iterator raises `StopIteration` when it cannot return the next item and that the `IndexError` which is raised for `item == 3` is handled internally. This is why looping over a `BasicIterable` with a `for` loop works as expected:

```
>>> for x in b:
...     print(x)
...
0
1
2
```

Here's another example in order to drive home the concept of how the iterator returned by `iter` tries to access items by index. `WrappedDict` does not inherit from `dict`, which means instances won't have an `__iter__` method.

```
class WrappedDict(object): # note: no inheritance from dict!
    def __init__(self, dic):
        self._dict = dic

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return self._dict[item] # delegate to dict.__getitem__
        except KeyError:
            raise IndexError
```

Note that calls to `__getitem__` are delegated to `dict.__getitem__` for which the square bracket notation is simply a shorthand.

```
>>> w = WrappedDict({-1: 'not printed',
...                   0: 'hi', 1: 'StackOverflow', 2: '!',
...                   4: 'not printed', 
...                   'x': 'not printed'})
>>> for x in w:
...     print(x)
... 
hi
StackOverflow
!
```

**On point 4 and 5: `iter` checks for an iterator when it calls `__iter__`**:

When `iter(o)` is called for an object `o`, `iter` will make sure that the return value of `__iter__`, if the method is present, is an iterator. This means that the returned object
must implement `__next__` (or `next` in Python 2) and `__iter__`. `iter` cannot perform any sanity checks for objects which only
provide `__getitem__`, because it has no way to check whether the items of the object are accessible by integer index.

```
class FailIterIterable(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return object() # not an iterator

class FailGetitemIterable(object):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        raise Exception
```

Note that constructing an iterator from `FailIterIterable` instances fails immediately, while constructing an iterator from `FailGetItemIterable` succeeds, but will throw an Exception on the first call to `__next__`.

```
>>> fii = FailIterIterable()
>>> iter(fii)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'object'
>>>
>>> fgi = FailGetitemIterable()
>>> it = iter(fgi)
>>> next(it)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/path/iterdemo.py", line 42, in __getitem__
    raise Exception
Exception
```

**On point 6: `__iter__` wins**

This one is straightforward. If an object implements `__iter__` and `__getitem__`, `iter` will call `__iter__`. Consider the following class

```
class IterWinsDemo(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(['__iter__', 'wins'])

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return ['__getitem__', 'wins'][item]
```

and the output when looping over an instance:

```
>>> iwd = IterWinsDemo()
>>> for x in iwd:
...     print(x)
...
__iter__
wins
```

**On point 7: your iterable classes should implement `__iter__`**

You might ask yourself why most builtin sequences like `list` implement an `__iter__` method when `__getitem__` would be sufficient.

```
class WrappedList(object): # note: no inheritance from list!
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self._list = lst

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._list[item]
```

After all, iteration over instances of the class above, which delegates calls to `__getitem__` to `list.__getitem__` (using the square bracket notation), will work fine:

```
>>> wl = WrappedList(['A', 'B', 'C'])
>>> for x in wl:
...     print(x)
... 
A
B
C
```

The reasons your custom iterables should implement `__iter__` are as follows:

1. If you implement `__iter__`, instances will be considered iterables, and `isinstance(o, collections.abc.Iterable)` will return `True`.
2. If the object returned by `__iter__` is not an iterator, `iter` will fail immediately and raise a `TypeError`.
3. The special handling of `__getitem__` exists for backwards compatibility reasons. Quoting again from Fluent Python:

> That is why any Python sequence is iterable: they all implement `__getitem__` . In fact,
> the standard sequences also implement `__iter__`, and yours should too, because the
> special handling of `__getitem__` exists for backward compatibility reasons and may be
> gone in the future (although it is not deprecated as I write this).

Comment: so it is safe to define a predicate `is_iterable` by returning `True` in the `try` block and `False` in the `except TypeError` block?

Comment: This is a great answer.  I think it highlights the unintuitive and unfortunate nature of the getitem protocol.  It should never have been added.

Comment: can you use `def isiterable(x): return hasattr(x, '__iter__') or hasattr(x, '__getitem__')` instead? Its a bit faster in my testing

Answer (score 106):

I've been studying this problem quite a bit lately. Based on that my conclusion is that nowadays this is the best approach:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable   # drop `.abc` with Python 2.7 or lower

def iterable(obj):
    return isinstance(obj, Iterable)
```

The above has been recommended already earlier, but the general consensus has been that using `iter()` would be better:

```py
def iterable(obj):
    try:
        iter(obj)
    except Exception:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

We've used `iter()` in our code as well for this purpose, but I've lately started to get more and more annoyed by objects which only have `__getitem__` being considered iterable. There are valid reasons to have `__getitem__` in a non-iterable object and with them the above code doesn't work well. As a real life example we can use [Faker](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/). The above code reports it being iterable but actually trying to iterate it causes an `AttributeError` (tested with Faker 4.0.2):

```py
>>> from faker import Faker
>>> fake = Faker()
>>> iter(fake)    # No exception, must be iterable
<iterator object at 0x7f1c71db58d0>
>>> list(fake)    # Ooops
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/.../site-packages/faker/proxy.py", line 59, in __getitem__
    return self._factory_map[locale.replace('-', '_')]
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

If we'd use `insinstance()`, we wouldn't accidentally consider Faker instances (or any other objects having only `__getitem__`) to be iterable:

```py
>>> from collections.abc import Iterable
>>> from faker import Faker
>>> isinstance(Faker(), Iterable)
False
```

Earlier answers commented that using `iter()` is safer as the old way to implement iteration in Python was based on `__getitem__` and the `isinstance()` approach wouldn't detect that. This may have been true with old Python versions, but based on my pretty exhaustive testing `isinstance()` works great nowadays. The only case where `isinstance()` didn't work but `iter()` did was with `UserDict` when using Python 2. If that's relevant, it's possible to use `isinstance(item, (Iterable, UserDict))` to get that covered.

Comment: Also `typing.Dict` is considered iterable by `iter(Dict)` but `list(Dict)` fails with error `TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got 0.`. As expected `isinstance(Dict, Iterable)` returns false.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, but for different reasons. Using `iter` caused some of our code that used "pre-caching" to slow down unnecessarily. If the `__iter__` code is slow, so will calling `iter`... any time you just want to see if something is iterable.

Comment: Would it be worth to add a note to that last bit, noting that Python 2 isn't actively being supported by the devs anymore, and shouldn't be used for new code if Python 3 is an option?

Comment: Just found a pretty weird corner case in which `isinstance(obj, Iterable)` fails: numpy 'arrays' of individual values. If you have 'obj = np.array(int(1))`, numpy will happily say `obj = array(1)`. The shape is an empty tuple, and `len(obj)` returns `TypeError: len() of unsized object`. HOWEVER! If you write: `isinstance(obj, Iterable)` you get...`True` .

Calamity

Answer (score 47):

Since **Python 3.5** you can use the [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module from the standard library for type related things:

```
from typing import Iterable

...

if isinstance(my_item, Iterable):
    print(True)
```

Comment: This will return `True` for single, string objects fyi.

Comment: @waydegg Yes, strings are iterable.

Comment: In Python **3.6** this code doesn't work. In **3.7** it does work. It looks like it will be [deprecated](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/) in **3.9**. `typing` is for type-checking tools (e.g. **MyPy**, **PyCharm**) and doesn't guarantee this behaviour. I think you meant to import the `Iterable` class from `collections.abc` instead.

Answer (score 33):

This isn't sufficient: the object returned by `__iter__` must implement the iteration protocol (i.e. `next` method). See the relevant section in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types).

In Python, a good practice is to "try and see" instead of "checking".

Comment: "duck typing" I believe? :)

Comment: @willem: or "don't ask for permission but for forgiveness" ;-)

Comment: @willem Both "permission" and "forgiveness" styles qualify as duck typing. If you ask what an object can *do* rather than what it *is*, that's duck typing.  If you use introspection, that's "permission"; if you just try to do it and see if it works or not, that's "forgiveness".

Comment: more about *don't ask what Python can do for you, ask what you can do for Python to work*

Answer (score 24):

In Python <= 2.5, you can't and shouldn't - iterable was an "informal" interface.

But since Python 2.6 and 3.0 you can leverage the new ABC (abstract base class) infrastructure along with some builtin ABCs which are available in the collections module:

```
from collections import Iterable

class MyObject(object):
    pass

mo = MyObject()
print isinstance(mo, Iterable)
Iterable.register(MyObject)
print isinstance(mo, Iterable)

print isinstance("abc", Iterable)
```

Now, whether this is desirable or actually works, is just a matter of conventions. As you can see, you *can* register a non-iterable object as Iterable - and it will raise an exception at runtime. Hence, isinstance acquires a "new" meaning - it just checks for "declared" type compatibility, which is a good way to go in Python.

On the other hand, if your object does not satisfy the interface you need, what are you going to do? Take the following example:

```
from collections import Iterable
from traceback import print_exc

def check_and_raise(x):
    if not isinstance(x, Iterable):
        raise TypeError, "%s is not iterable" % x
    else:
        for i in x:
            print i

def just_iter(x):
    for i in x:
        print i


class NotIterable(object):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        check_and_raise(5)
    except:
        print_exc()
        print

    try:
        just_iter(5)
    except:
        print_exc()
        print

    try:
        Iterable.register(NotIterable)
        ni = NotIterable()
        check_and_raise(ni)
    except:
        print_exc()
        print
```

If the object doesn't satisfy what you expect, you just throw a TypeError, but if the proper ABC has been registered, your check is unuseful. On the contrary, if the `__iter__` method is available Python will automatically recognize object of that class as being Iterable.

So, if you just expect an iterable, iterate over it and forget it. On the other hand, if you need to do different things depending on input type, you might find the ABC infrastructure pretty useful.

Comment: don't use bare `except:` in the example code for beginners. It promotes bad practice.

Comment: J.F.S: I wouldn't, but I needed to go through multiple exception-raising code and I didn't want to catch the specific exception... I think the purpose of this code is pretty clear.

Answer (score 21):

```
try:
  #treat object as iterable
except TypeError, e:
  #object is not actually iterable
```

Don't run checks to see <s>if your duck really is a duck</s> to see if it is iterable or not, treat it as if it was and complain if it wasn't.

Comment: Technically, during iteration your computation might throw a `TypeError` and throw you off here, but basically yes.

Comment: I know in .NET it was a bad idea to have exceptions handle program flow, as exceptions were **slow**. How quickly does python handle exceptions?

Comment: @willem: Please use timeit to perform a benchmark.  Python exceptions are often faster than if-statements.  They can take a slightly shorter path through the interpreter.

Comment: @willem: IronPython has slow (compared to CPython) exceptions.

Comment: A working try: statement is really fast. So if you have few exceptions, try-except is fast. If you expect many exceptions, “if” can be faster.

Comment: Shouldn't the exception object be caught by adding "`as e`" after `TypeError` instead of by adding "`, e`"?

Comment: here's a good rule of thumb, `try` is faster than `if`, but `except` is slower than `else`. exception lookup is generally slow regardless of what language you're using. Note that this doesn't include execution between `elif` and `finally`, where a blank `try`/`finally` is generally faster than a blank `if True`/`else`. but **be smart and use this stuff wizely**, `finally` is generally used for context management rather than basic logic and shouldn't be substituted due to what it ensures.

Comment: corporate slave coding

Answer (score 18):

You could try this:

```
def iterable(a):
    try:
        (x for x in a)
        return True
    except TypeError:
        return False
```

If we can make a generator that iterates over it (but never use the generator so it doesn't take up space), it's iterable. Seems like a "duh" kind of thing. Why do you need to determine if a variable is iterable in the first place?

Comment: What about `iterable(itertools.repeat(0))`? :)

Comment: @badp, the `(x for x in a)` just creates a generator, it doesn't do any iteration on a.

Comment: Is trying `(x for x in a)` precisely equivalent to trying `iterator = iter(a)`? Or there are some cases where the two are different?

Comment: Isn't `for _ in a: break` more straightforward ? Is it slower ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D that's bad if the tested object is an iterator that's iterated over afterwards (it will be 1 item short since it's position can't be reset), creating garbage generators doesn't iterate over the object as they're not iterated over, though I'm not certain that it will 100% raise a TypeError if not iterable.

Answer (score 15):

The best solution I've found so far:

`hasattr(obj, '__contains__')`

which basically checks if the object implements the `in` operator.

**Advantages** (none of the other solutions has all three):

- it is an expression (works as a **lambda**, as opposed to the **try...except** variant)
- it is (should be) implemented by all iterables, including **strings** (as opposed to `__iter__`)
- works on any Python >= 2.5

Notes:

- the Python philosophy of "ask for forgiveness, not permission" doesn't work well when e.g. in a list you have both iterables and non-iterables and you need to treat each element differently according to it's type (treating iterables on try and non-iterables on except *would* work, but it would look butt-ugly and misleading)
- solutions to this problem which attempt to actually iterate over the object (e.g. [x for x in obj]) to check if it's iterable may induce significant performance penalties for large iterables (especially if you just need the first few elements of the iterable, for example) and should be avoided

Comment: Nice, but why not use the collections module as proposed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-a-variable-is-iterable/1952481#1952481?  Seems more expressive to me.

Comment: It's shorter (and doesn't require additional imports) without losing any clarity: having a "contains" method feels like a natural way to check if something is a collection of objects.

Comment: Just because something can contain something doesn't necessarily mean it's iterable.  For example, a user can check if a point is in a 3D cube, but how would you iterate through this object?

Comment: This is incorrect. An iterable itself does not support __contains__, at least with Python 3.4.

Answer (score 14):

I found a nice solution [here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/514838-how-test-if-object-sequence-iterable):

```
isiterable = lambda obj: isinstance(obj, basestring) \
    or getattr(obj, '__iter__', False)
```

Answer (score 11):

According to the [Python 2 Glossary](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable), iterables are

> all sequence types (such as `list`, `str`, and `tuple`) and some non-sequence types like `dict` and `file` and objects of any classes you define with an `__iter__()` or `__getitem__()` method. Iterables can be used in a for loop and in many other places where a sequence is needed (zip(), map(), ...). When an iterable object is passed as an argument to the built-in function iter(), it returns an iterator for the object.

Of course, given the general coding style for Python based on the fact that it's “Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.”, the general expectation is to use

```
try:
    for i in object_in_question:
        do_something
except TypeError:
    do_something_for_non_iterable
```

But if you need to check it explicitly, you can test for an iterable by `hasattr(object_in_question, "__iter__") or hasattr(object_in_question, "__getitem__")`. You need to check for both, because `str`s don't have an `__iter__` method (at least not in Python 2, in Python 3 they do) and because `generator` objects don't have a `__getitem__` method.

Answer (score 9):

I often find convenient, inside my scripts, to define an `iterable` function.
(Now incorporates Alfe's suggested simplification):

```
import collections

def iterable(obj):
    return isinstance(obj, collections.Iterable):
```

so you can test if any object is iterable in the very readable form

```
if iterable(obj):
    # act on iterable
else:
    # not iterable
```

as you would do with the`callable` function

EDIT: if you have numpy installed, you can simply do: from `numpy import iterable`, 
which is simply something like

```
def iterable(obj):
    try: iter(obj)
    except: return False
    return True
```

If you do not have numpy, you can simply implement this code, or the one above.

Comment: Whenever you do sth like `if x: return True` `else: return False` (with `x` being boolean) you can write this as `return x`.  In your case `return isinstance(…)` without any `if`.

Comment: Since you acknowledge that Alfe's solution is better, why didn't you edit your answer to simply say that?  Instead, you now have BOTH versions in your answer. Unnecessary verbosity. Submitting an edit to fix this.

Comment: You should catch "TypeError" in the ` except: return False ` line. Catching everything is a bad pattern.

Comment: Know that. I translated that piece of code from the NumPy library, which uses the generic exception.

Comment: Just because a code is taken from NumPy doesn't mean it's good... pattern or not, the only time catching everything should be done is if you're explicitly error handling inside your program.

Answer (score 5):

[pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) has a built-in function like that:

```
from pandas.util.testing import isiterable
```

Comment: this however just looks whether there is `__iter__` and not really cares about sequences and similar.

Answer (score 4):

It's always eluded me as to why python has `callable(obj) -> bool` but not `iterable(obj) -> bool`...
surely it's easier to do `hasattr(obj,'__call__')` even if it is slower.

Since just about every other answer recommends using `try`/`except TypeError`, where testing for exceptions is generally considered bad practice among any language, here's an implementation of `iterable(obj) -> bool` I've grown more fond of and use often:

For python 2's sake, I'll use a lambda just for that extra performance boost...
(in python 3 it doesn't matter what you use for defining the function, `def` has roughly the same speed as `lambda`)

```
iterable = lambda obj: hasattr(obj,'__iter__') or hasattr(obj,'__getitem__')
```

Note that this function executes faster for objects with `__iter__` since it doesn't test for `__getitem__`.

Most iterable objects should rely on `__iter__` where special-case objects fall back to `__getitem__`, though either is required for an object to be iterable.
(and since this is standard, it affects C objects as well)

Comment: he doesn't provide working code, let alone talk about python performance... 
although this answer was really just for convenience like I've seen done numerous times on here.

Comment: "where testing for exceptions is generally considered bad practice among any language" Python is not included in your generalization. Python handles exceptions very efficiently, and idiomatic Python necessitates the use of try...except blocks as part of its duck typing philosophy as mentioned in numerous answers to this question.

Comment: "Python handles exceptions very efficiently" I'm afraid I have to heavily disagree, `except` is one of the slowest, most inefficient, keywords in python, it has it's purpose, but should not be used everywhere, unless you want the lowest performing code imaginable, given `except` is actually invoked... `try` is faster than `if`, but `except` is much slower than `else` due to exception lookups.

Comment: There is so much literature on the EAFP philosophy employed by Python, even on StackOverflow. Python, when compared to other languages such as C++, handles exceptions more efficiently because it is a higher level language. It's science--the algorithm is cheaper because of the way that Python processes the code.  I liked the answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835756/using-try-vs-if-in-python

Comment: "Python, when compared to other languages such as C++, handles exceptions more efficiently because it is a higher level language" efficiency has nothing to do with being higher level, it has everything to do with how the CPU ultimately executes the bytecode/machine-code, which ultimately yes, python is more efficient since exceptions are PyObject instances in C, where as exceptions in C++ are something completely different, but that still doesn't change the fact that `except` is the most inefficient keyword in python, and makes your execution incredibly slow if invoked often.

Comment: Let's rewind. It sounds like you are trying to encourage Python programmers to use  conditions to check for potential errors rather than to use the idiomatic way with `try...except` blocks. Please clarify your position on that matter.

Comment: Indeed I am, the conditional approach is generally faster, since `except` is horribly inefficient due to exception lookups, however again, there are places where `except` should be used where it won't be invoked often, such as within a run loop where it's known the execution will only fail 5% or so of the time, as this ensures runtime stability. However, `except` should NOT be used as a substitute for conditional testing, where the especially where the failure rate is above ~30% as this will greatly slow down your runtime.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of ways to check if an object is iterable:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable
myobject = 'Roster'
  
if isinstance(myobject , Iterable):
    print(f"{myobject } is iterable") 
else:
   print(f"strong text{myobject } is not iterable")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def is_iterable(x):
    try:
        0 in x
    except TypeError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

This will say yes to all manner of iterable objects, but it will **say no to strings in Python 2**. (That's what I want for example when a recursive function could take a string or a container of strings.  In that situation, [asking forgiveness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1952481/673991) may lead to obfuscode, and it's better to ask permission first.)

```
import numpy

class Yes:
    def __iter__(self):
        yield 1;
        yield 2;
        yield 3;

class No:
    pass

class Nope:
    def __iter__(self):
        return 'nonsense'

assert is_iterable(Yes())
assert is_iterable(range(3))
assert is_iterable((1,2,3))   # tuple
assert is_iterable([1,2,3])   # list
assert is_iterable({1,2,3})   # set
assert is_iterable({1:'one', 2:'two', 3:'three'})   # dictionary
assert is_iterable(numpy.array([1,2,3]))
assert is_iterable(bytearray("not really a string", 'utf-8'))

assert not is_iterable(No())
assert not is_iterable(Nope())
assert not is_iterable("string")
assert not is_iterable(42)
assert not is_iterable(True)
assert not is_iterable(None)
```

Many other strategies here will say yes to strings. Use them if that's what you want.

```
import collections
import numpy

assert isinstance("string", collections.Iterable)
assert isinstance("string", collections.Sequence)
assert numpy.iterable("string")
assert iter("string")
assert hasattr("string", '__getitem__')
```

Note: is_iterable() will say yes to strings of type `bytes` and `bytearray`.

- `bytes` objects in Python 3 are iterable `True == is_iterable(b"string") == is_iterable("string".encode('utf-8'))` There is no such type in Python 2.
- `bytearray` objects in Python 2 and 3 are iterable `True == is_iterable(bytearray(b"abc"))`

The O.P. `hasattr(x, '__iter__')` approach will say yes to strings in Python 3 and no in Python 2 (no matter whether `''` or `b''` or `u''`). Thanks to @LuisMasuelli for noticing it will also let you down on a buggy `__iter__`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way, respecting the Python's [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), is to catch the error (Python knows perfectly what does it expect from an object to become an iterator):

```
class A(object):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return something

class B(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        # Return a compliant iterator. Just an example
        return iter([])

class C(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        # Return crap
        return 1

class D(object): pass

def iterable(obj):
    try:
        iter(obj)
        return True
    except:
        return False

assert iterable(A())
assert iterable(B())
assert iterable(C())
assert not iterable(D())
```

**Notes**:

1. It is irrelevant the distinction whether the object is not iterable, or a buggy `__iter__` has been implemented, if the exception type is the same: anyway you will not be able to iterate the object.
2. I think I understand your concern: How does `callable` exists as a check if I could also rely on duck typing to raise an `AttributeError` if `__call__` is not defined for my object, but that's not the case for iterable checking?

   I don't know the answer, but you can either implement the function I (and other users) gave, or just catch the exception in your code (your implementation in that part will be like the function I wrote - just ensure you isolate the iterator creation from the rest of the code so you can capture the exception and distinguish it from another `TypeError`.

Answer (score 2):

The `isiterable` func at the following code returns `True` if object is iterable. if it's not iterable returns `False`

```
def isiterable(object_):
    return hasattr(type(object_), "__iter__")
```

example

```
fruits = ("apple", "banana", "peach")
isiterable(fruits) # returns True

num = 345
isiterable(num) # returns False

isiterable(str) # returns False because str type is type class and it's not iterable.

hello = "hello dude !"
isiterable(hello) # returns True because as you know string objects are iterable
```

Comment: so many detailed answers above with many upvotes and you throw in an unexplained answer... meh

Comment: Please do not post bare code. Also include an explanation of what this is doing.

Answer (score 2):

In my code I used to check for non iterable objects:

`hasattr(myobject,'__trunc__')`

This is quite quick and can be used to check for iterables too (use `not`).

I'm not 100% sure if this solution works for all objects, maybe other can give a some more background on it. `__trunc__` method seams to be related to numerical types (all objects that can be rounded to integers needs it). But I didn't found any object that contains `__trunc__` together with `__iter__` or `__getitem__`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking for the `__iter__` attribute, you could check for the `__len__` attribute, which is implemented by every python builtin iterable, including strings.

```
>>> hasattr(1, "__len__")
False
>>> hasattr(1.3, "__len__")
False
>>> hasattr("a", "__len__")
True
>>> hasattr([1,2,3], "__len__")
True
>>> hasattr({1,2}, "__len__")
True
>>> hasattr({"a":1}, "__len__")
True
>>> hasattr(("a", 1), "__len__")
True
```

None-iterable objects would not implement this for obvious reasons. However, it does not catch user-defined iterables that do not implement it, nor do generator expressions, which `iter` can deal with. However, this can be done in a line, and adding a simple `or` expression checking for generators would fix this problem. (Note that writing `type(my_generator_expression) == generator` would throw a `NameError`. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416538/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-a-generator-object-in-python) answer instead.)

> You can use GeneratorType from types:
>
> ```
> >>> import types
> >>> types.GeneratorType
> <class 'generator'>
> >>> gen = (i for i in range(10))
> >>> isinstance(gen, types.GeneratorType)
> True
> ```
>
> --- accepted answer by utdemir

(This makes it useful for checking if you can call `len` on the object though.)

Comment: unfortunately not all iterable objects use `__len__`... for this case, it's usually the improper use of calculating distance between 2 objects. where `obj.dist()` could be easily substituted.

Comment: Yeah. Most user defined iterables implement iter and getitem but not len. However, built in types do, and if you want to check if you can call len function on it, checking for len is more secure. But you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Not really *"correct"* but can serve as quick check of most common types like strings, tuples, floats, etc...

```
>>> '__iter__' in dir('sds')
True
>>> '__iter__' in dir(56)
False
>>> '__iter__' in dir([5,6,9,8])
True
>>> '__iter__' in dir({'jh':'ff'})
True
>>> '__iter__' in dir({'jh'})
True
>>> '__iter__' in dir(56.9865)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late to the party but I asked myself this question and saw this then thought of an answer. I don't know if someone already posted this. But essentially, I've noticed that all iterable types have *__getitem__()* in their dict. This is how you would check if an object was an iterable without even trying. (Pun intended)

```
def is_attr(arg):
    return '__getitem__' in dir(arg)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is unreliable. [Example](https://pastebin.com/7UxbRwCf)

Comment: Set objects are another counterexample.

Comment: How is that a pun?

Comment: Maybe write `'__iter__' in dir(arg)` instead of `'__getitem__' in dir(arg)`

Comment: performance is `O(n)`, since `dir()` returns a list, and `set(dir())` is even slower since it's performance is `O(n)(1)`, due to needing to convert the list into a set before calling `set.__contains__`, which is `O(1)`, but as stated earlier, not all iterables use `__getitem__`, thus it's unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with various functions, I believe this is the fastest way to reliably tell if an object is iterable, although it involves bare exceptions:

```py
def isiterable(x):
    if  hasattr(x, '__iter__'): return not isinstance(x, type)
    if hasattr(x, '__getitem__'):
        try:
            x[0]
            return True
        except Exception:
            return False
    return False
```

This is not a perfect solution, but as I explain below, this one is among the most reliable ones. There are two edge cases that I can think of, where this function will fail: first is an non-iterable object that has a `__getitem__` method and `x[0]`. Second is an iterable `type` object.

If you don't want bare exceptions, there are a few methods I've described below, and they all have different drawbacks.

### What can be iterable

In order to be iterable, an object needs either `__getitem__` or `__iter__` methods.

However some objects with `__getitem__` are not iterable, for example:

```py
class Getitem_ButNotIterable:
    def __init__(self): self.dict_ = {"a":1, "b":2}
    def __getitem__(self, item:str): return self.dict_[item]

for i in Getitem_ButNotIterable(): 
    pass

>> KeyError: 0
```

Worth mentioning that running `iter(Getitem_ButNotIterable())` will not raise an exception unless you actually try to iterate over it, so that method isn't fully reliable.

And types can have `__iter__` attribute, but they are (usually) not iterable either.

```py
hasattr(list, "__iter__") >> True
for i in list: pass >> TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

However types can actually be iterable, that is if their metaclass has `__iter__` method.

The hardest edge case is this one:

```
class Getitem_ButNotIterable2:
    def __init__(self): self.dict_ = {0:1, "b":2}
    def __getitem__(self, item:str): return self.dict_[item]
```

If you try to iterate through this, it will call `x[0]` which returns 0, but then it will call `x[1]` which will raise an **KeyError**, which iter does not catch. Unfortunately I don't think there is an easy way to detect those.

### Methods of testing if object is iterable

To test various methods, I created 40 different iterables and non-iterables, and tried a bunch of functions for 1_000_000 times on each iterable/non-iterable, and wrote the total time everything took. Method at the beginning takes 8 seconds for reference.

---

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable
def is_iterable1(x): 
    return isinstance(x, Iterable)
```

Took 17 seconds. This checks if object has an `__iter__` method, therefore it will fail to recognize iterable objects that only have `__getitem__`.

Worth mentioning that if you use the deprecated `typing.Iterable` instead, the time goes up to 50 seconds.

---

```
def is_iterable2(x): 
    return hasattr(x, "__iter__")
```

Took 5 seconds. This is almost equivalent to `isinstance(x, Iterable)`, however are is additional false positives: types, like `is_iterable2(list)` will return True.

---

```
def is_iterable3(x): 
    return hasattr(x, "__iter__") and hasattr(x, "__getitem__")
```

Took 7 seconds. Unlike above two methods, this will recognize iterable `__getitem__` objects, but also give false positives on non-iterable `__getitem__` objects, and types with those methods

---

```py
def is_iterable4(x):
    try:
        iter(x)
        return True
    except TypeError:
       return False
    return True
```

Took 36 seconds. This will produce a false positive on non-iterable objects that have `__getitem__`. Changing `iter(x)` to `(i for i in x)` is equivalent. This is a good method if you don't want bare exceptions.

---

```py
def is_iterable5(x):
    try:
        0 in x
    except TypeError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Took 50 seconds. This will raise an exception on non-iterable objects that have `__getitem__`.

---

```
def is_iterable6(x):
    try: 
        for _ in x: return True
    except Exception: return False
    return True
```

Took 33 seconds. We are getting into bare exceptions now, but I can't think of any other ways to make it more reliable. There can be some edge cases where you don't want to iterate over some object outside of the usual usage, as this could mess the internal state.

---

```py
def is_iterable7(x):
    if  hasattr(x.__class__, '__iter__'): return True
    if hasattr(x, '__getitem__'):
        try:
            x[0]
            return True
        except Exception:
            return False
    return False
```

Took 23 seconds. Correctly evaluates almost everything as it won't give a true negative for types that have `__iter__` method. There are still two edge cases: non-iterable object with `__getitem__`, and iterable classes, ones that have a metaclass with `__iter__` method. However I don't think it is possible to get easily more reliable than this,

---

```py
def is_iterable8(x):
    if  hasattr(x, '__iter__'): return not isinstance(x, type)
    if hasattr(x, '__getitem__'):
        try:
            x[0]
            return True
        except Exception:
            return False
    return False
```

Took 8 seconds. Should be equivalent to function above, so, unless you expect classes with metaclasses with `__iter__`, and if you don't mind bare exceptions, this seems to be the best way to tell if an object is iterable.

---

Bonus:

```py
def super_slow_but_is_almost_definitely_iterable(x):
    try:
        for i,v in enumerate(x):
            if i == 1000:break
        return True
    except Exception: return False
```

Took just 40 seconds, surprisingly. This is the most reliable way, except it involves iterating so in some edge cases it will mess up the internal state. Also if you have objects that are expensive to iterate through, this will become extremely slow.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe just write `hasattr(obj, "__iter__")`

Or... something like this might work:

```python
def is_iterable(obj: object) -> bool:
    return hasattr(obj, "__iter__")
```