# Handle iterable and non-iterable seamlessly

Tags: python, iterable

Could you let me know how I can optimize the following code?

```
def f(y, list_or_elem):
  if getattr(list_or_elem, '__iter__'):
    y = max(y, *list_or_elem)
  else:
    y = max(y, list_or_elem)
```

Comment: Don't forget that strings are iterable too, so `f("xxx", "abz")` will return "z", which is probably not what you want.

Comment: On second thoughts your function does not return anything - it assigns the result to y, which is local to the function.  It will do nothing, whatever arguments you pass it.

Answer (score 1):

The best optimization of all would be to avoid such silliness as taking "either a list or a single element" as an argument.  But, if you insist, it's better to use a try/except to remove the anomaly ASAP and make what's sure to be an iterable:

```
try: iter(list_or_elem)
except TypeError: iterable = [list_or_elem]
else: iterable = list_or_elem
y = max(y, *iterable)
```

Comment: Similar answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-a-variable-is-iterable

Answer (score 0):

if you are willing to have add flatten function in your code (theres a good one [here](http://rightfootin.blogspot.com/2006/09/more-on-python-flatten.html)) which can basically take a list of lists of lists of... and bring it down to a single list, you can do something like

```
y = max(flatten([y, list_or_elem]))
```

Comment: ps: if you go for this, add the use the iter_flatten method specified on that page