# python: how to identify if a variable is an array or a scalar

Tags: python, arrays, variables, scalar

I have a function that takes the argument `NBins`. I want to make a call to this function with a scalar `50` or an array `[0, 10, 20, 30]`. How can I identify within the function, what the length of `NBins` is? or said differently, if it is a scalar or a vector?

I tried this:

```
>>> N=[2,3,5]
>>> P = 5
>>> len(N)
3
>>> len(P)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
>>>
```

As you see, I can't apply `len` to `P`, since it's not an array.... Is there something like `isarray` or `isscalar` in python?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried testing for it's `type`?

Answer (score 548, accepted):

```
>>> import collections.abc
>>> isinstance([0, 10, 20, 30], collections.abc.Sequence)
True
>>> isinstance(50, collections.abc.Sequence)
False
```

**note**: `isinstance` also supports a tuple of classes, check `type(x) in (..., ...)` should be avoided and is unnecessary.

You may also wanna check `not isinstance(x, (str, unicode))`

As noted by [@2080](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807011/python-how-to-identify-if-a-variable-is-an-array-or-a-scalar/16807050?noredirect=1#comment128960203_16807050) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937114/python-check-if-an-object-is-a-sequence#comment88639515_2937122)  this won't work for `numpy` arrays. eg.

```
>>> import collections.abc
>>> import numpy as np
>>> isinstance((1, 2, 3), collections.abc.Sequence)
True
>>> isinstance(np.array([1, 2, 3]), collections.abc.Sequence)
False
```

In which case you may try the answer from [@jpaddison3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19773559/1219006):

```
>>> hasattr(np.array([1, 2, 3]), "__len__")
True
>>> hasattr([1, 2, 3], "__len__")
True
>>> hasattr((1, 2, 3), "__len__")
True
```

However as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937114/python-check-if-an-object-is-a-sequence#comment127867518_63465553), this is not perfect either, and will incorrectly (at least according to me) classify dictionaries as sequences whereas `isinstance` with `collections.abc.Sequence` classifies correctly:

```
>>> hasattr({"a": 1}, "__len__")
True
>>> from numpy.distutils.misc_util import is_sequence
>>> is_sequence({"a": 1})
True
>>> isinstance({"a": 1}, collections.abc.Sequence)
False
```

You could customise your solution to something like this, add more types to `isinstance` depending on your needs:

```
>>> isinstance(np.array([1, 2, 3]), (collections.abc.Sequence, np.ndarray))
True
>>> isinstance([1, 2, 3], (collections.abc.Sequence, np.ndarray))
True
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't imagine inverting `list` to get false for scalars... thanks

Comment: While this is a great answer, `collections.Sequence` is an ABC for string as well, so that should be taken into account. I'm using something like `if type(x) is not str and isinstance(x, collections.Sequence):`. This isn't great, but it is reliable.

Comment: @bbenne10 sure, but avoid `type`, and also check `not isinstance(x, (str, unicode))` on Python 2

Comment: Why did you say "check type(x) in (..., ...) should be avoided and is unnecessary."? If you say so, that would be very kind to explain why, maybe I'm not the only one to wonder why it should be avoided.

Comment: @OlivierPons https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python

Comment: The answer is ok for checking for an array, but not for validating that a variable is a scalar, unless Mapping like dict are considered scalar since `not isinstance({"a", 1, "b":3}, (list, collection.Sequence))` would return true which does not mean that the variable (here a dict) is a scalad.

Comment: `collections.Sequence` --> `collections.abc.Sequence` [may](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/thread/EYLXCGGJOUMZSE5X35ILW3UNTJM3MCRE/) be required in Python 3.9 or 3.10.

Comment: This won't work for numpy arrays

Comment: unfortunately, `isinstance(np.array(1), (collections.abc.Sequence, np.ndarray))` (i.e., a numpy scalar) returns `True`, but `np.array(1)[0]` is an `IndexError`

Answer (score 174):

Previous answers assume that the array is a python standard list.  As someone who uses numpy often, I'd recommend a very pythonic test of:

```
if hasattr(N, "__len__")
```

Comment: strings have a `__len__` attribute (so I guess, not technically a scalar type)

Comment: `if hasattr(N, '__len__') and (not isinstance(N, str))` would properly account for strings.

Comment: Also account for dict on Python 3

Comment: This does not work for Iterators.  `len(iter([1,2,3]))` throws "TypeError: object of type 'list_iterator' has no len()"

Answer (score 78):

Combining @jamylak and @jpaddison3's answers together, if you need to be robust against numpy arrays as the input and handle them in the same way as lists, you should use

```
import numpy as np
isinstance(P, (list, tuple, np.ndarray))
```

This is robust against subclasses of list, tuple and numpy arrays.

And if you want to be robust against all other subclasses of sequence as well (not just list and tuple), use

```
import collections
import numpy as np
isinstance(P, (collections.Sequence, np.ndarray))
```

Why should you do things this way with `isinstance` and not compare `type(P)` with a target value? Here is an example, where we make and study the behaviour of `NewList`, a trivial subclass of list.

```
>>> class NewList(list):
...     isThisAList = '???'
... 
>>> x = NewList([0,1])
>>> y = list([0,1])
>>> print x
[0, 1]
>>> print y
[0, 1]
>>> x==y
True
>>> type(x)
<class '__main__.NewList'>
>>> type(x) is list
False
>>> type(y) is list
True
>>> type(x).__name__
'NewList'
>>> isinstance(x, list)
True
```

Despite `x` and `y` comparing as equal, handling them by `type` would result in different behaviour. However, since `x` is an instance of a subclass of `list`, using `isinstance(x,list)` gives the desired behaviour and treats `x` and `y` in the same manner.

Comment: This is the answer that most suited my needs. I just added set, too. Because I don't want to be robust against dicts. `isinstance(P, (list, tuple, set, np.ndarray))`

Answer (score 65):

Is there an equivalent to isscalar() in numpy? Yes.

```
>>> np.isscalar(3.1)
True
>>> np.isscalar([3.1])
False
>>> np.isscalar(False)
True
>>> np.isscalar('abcd')
True
```

Comment: It would be better and an example :`>>> np.isscalar('abcd')` returns `True`.

Comment: thanks! this is a much more general example than any of the above and should be preferred. It's also a direct answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Nice. Although one gotcha is that isscalar(None) returns False. Numpy implements this as `return (isinstance(num, generic)
            or type(num) in ScalarType
            or isinstance(num, numbers.Number))`

Comment: **No, sadly.** The `numpy.isscalar()` function suffers a number of irreconcilable design flaws and will *probably* be deprecated at some future revision. To paraphrase [official documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isscalar.html): "In almost all cases `np.ndim(x) == 0` should be used instead of `np.isscaler(x)`, as the former will also correctly return true for 0d arrays." A robust forward-compatible alternative to `numpy.isscalar()` would thus be to trivially wrap `numpy.ndim()`: e.g., `def is_scalar(obj): return np.ndim(obj) == 0`

Comment: Actually this should not be upvoted because `np.isscalar` is confusing. Official doc suggested using `np.array.ndim` everywhere, i.e. `np.isscalar(np.array(12))` is False while it should be considered as scalar since `np.array(12).ndim` is 0.

Comment: It doesn't work on mappings.
`np.ndim({'a':'b', 'c':'d'}) == 0`

Answer (score 31):

While, @jamylak's approach is the better one, here is an alternative approach

```
>>> N=[2,3,5]
>>> P = 5
>>> type(P) in (tuple, list)
False
>>> type(N) in (tuple, list)
True
```

Comment: It would have been great if the person who downvoted the answer would have given a reason too.

Comment: i've actually upvoted, but then realized that it deosn't work in 2.7:>>> p=[]
>>> type(p) in (list)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

Comment: @OlegGryb: Try `type(p) in (list, )`.

Comment: ah, it's a tuple on the right, not a list, got it, thanks and it works now. I regret, I can't upvote 2 times - the best solution so far :)

Answer (score 8):

Another alternative approach (use of class **name** property):

```
N = [2,3,5]
P = 5

type(N).__name__ == 'list'
True

type(P).__name__ == 'int'
True

type(N).__name__ in ('list', 'tuple')
True
```

No need to import anything.

Comment: There's no advantage to doing this than just `type(N) is list` or `type(N) is int`. And as other answers have mentioned, doing a strict type equality check is usually less preferable to an `isinstance()` check, which can account for subclasses.

Comment: Nice! Saves you when strings are fighting with other iterables!

Answer (score 5):

Here is the best approach I have found: Check existence of `__len__` and `__getitem__`.

You may ask why? The reasons includes:

1. The popular method `isinstance(obj, abc.Sequence)` fails on some objects including PyTorch's Tensor because they do not implement `__contains__`.
2. Unfortunately, there is nothing in Python's collections.abc that checks for only `__len__` and `__getitem__` which I feel are minimal methods for array-like objects.
3. It works on list, tuple, ndarray, Tensor etc.

So without further ado:

```
def is_array_like(obj, string_is_array=False, tuple_is_array=True):
    result = hasattr(obj, "__len__") and hasattr(obj, '__getitem__') 
    if result and not string_is_array and isinstance(obj, (str, abc.ByteString)):
        result = False
    if result and not tuple_is_array and isinstance(obj, tuple):
        result = False
    return result
```

Note that I've added default parameters because most of the time you might want to consider strings as values, not arrays. Similarly for tuples.

Comment: This doesn't work well on scalar (TensorFlow) tensors, because they have a __len__ method but raise an error if you try to call it on a scalar tensor:  TypeError: Scalar tensor has no `len()`. Kind of annoying behaviour on the part of TensorFlow...

Comment: To deal with this I find myself first doing something like if hasattr(obj,"shape") and obj.shape==() to check for these "scalar array" cases.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question in the title, a direct way to tell if a variable is a scalar is to try to convert it to a float. If you get `TypeError`, it's not.

```
N = [1, 2, 3]
try:
    float(N)
except TypeError:
    print('it is not a scalar')
else:
    print('it is a scalar')
```

Comment: Is anything wrong with this answer? The chosen answer fails when doing `isinstance(np.arange(10), collections.Sequence)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> N=[2,3,5]
>>> P = 5
>>> type(P)==type(0)
True
>>> type([1,2])==type(N)
True
>>> type(P)==type([1,2])
False
```

Answer (score 3):

I am surprised that such a basic question doesn't seem to have an immediate answer in python.
It seems to me that nearly all proposed answers use some kind of type
checking, that is usually not advised in python and they seem restricted to a specific case (they fail with different numerical types or generic iteratable objects that are not tuples or lists).

For me, what works better is importing numpy and using array.size, for example:

```
>>> a=1
>>> np.array(a)
Out[1]: array(1)

>>> np.array(a).size
Out[2]: 1

>>> np.array([1,2]).size
Out[3]: 2

>>> np.array('125')
Out[4]: 1
```

Note also:

```
>>> len(np.array([1,2]))

Out[5]: 2
```

but:

```
>>> len(np.array(a))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-f5055b93f729> in <module>()
----> 1 len(np.array(a))

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Comment: I'm also surprised that none of them seem to deal with generators either.

Comment: It also doesn't work on mappings:  `>>> np.array({1:2, 3:4}).size == 1`

Comment: these are because the np.array function creates an array of dtype `object`, with a single element containing the dictionary (or the generator). It is different using `np.array(list(a.items())).size` or `np.array(list(a.keys())).size` gives a different result.

Answer (score 2):

You can check data type of variable.

```
N = [2,3,5]
P = 5
type(P)
```

It will give you out put as data type of P.

```
<type 'int'>
```

So that you can differentiate that it is an integer or an array.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `size` instead of `len`!

```
>>> from numpy import size
>>> N = [2, 3, 5]
>>> size(N)
3
>>> N = array([2, 3, 5])
>>> size(N)
3
>>> P = 5
>>> size(P)
1
```

Comment: NameError: name 'size' is not defined

Comment: That's true. I was using numpy size without noticing it. You need: from numpy import size

Comment: `np.size(5)` and `np.size([5])` are both == `1`, so this doesn't correctly distinguish type (i.e., identify a scalar), which I believe is the goal.

Comment: This is an interesting remark.
Original question refers to isscalar, which is a Matlab function. In Matlab, there is absolutely no difference between a scalar and an array of size 1, may it be a vector or a N-dim array. IMHO, this is a plus for Matlab.

Comment: Madness. That would mean `{} == {{}}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use function `isinstance(object, classinfo)` in Python.

```py
>>> isinstance(5, list)
False

>>>  isinstance([2, 3, 5], list)
True
```

[See ducomentation for this function.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)

Answer (score 1):

Since the general guideline in Python is to ask for forgiveness rather than permission, I think the most pythonic way to detect a string/scalar from a sequence is to check if it contains an integer:

```
try:
    1 in a
    print('{} is a sequence'.format(a))
except TypeError:
    print('{} is a scalar or string'.format(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Determining if something is a scalar is easier (there are fewer ambiguities) than determining if it is a sequence (array/list/vector, etc.).

as @jamylak notes, `not numpy.distutils.misc_util.is_sequence` will identify scalars well. It simply checks that the input is not a `str` AND does not have a `__len__` attribute.

But just because something is not a scalar does not mean it is a sequence. As @jamylak notes, this also identifies dictionaries as sequences, which differs from collections.abc.Sequence (`dict` is `Iterable`, but not a `Sequence`).

`collections.abc.Sequence` returns `True` for a `list` but not for a numpy array (it also returns True for a `str`):

```py
issubclass(type(np.array([1])), collections.abc.Sequence) == False
```

`collections.abc.Iterable` returns `True` for a (normal) numpy array, but unfortunately also returns True for a zero-dimensional numpy array:

```py
issubclass(type(np.array(1)), collections.abc.Iterable) == True
```

which cannot actually be iterated over, indexed into, and does not have a `__len__`.

As the numpy [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isscalar.html) suggests, numpy.isscalar should not be used. However, their suggested alternative, `np.ndim(x) == 0` also doesn't work as I would expect.

It correctly calls `np.array(1)` a scalar (`np.ndim(np.array(1)) == 0`), however, as noted in the numpy.isscalar documentation, it also calls almost everything that is not a list or np.array a scalar, including strings, dicts, and other objects.

The only thing I've found that reliably works is

```py
def is_scalar(x):
    return issubclass(type(np.asarray(x)[()]), numbers.Number)

def is_sequence(x):
    if is_scalar(x):
        return False
    return np.ndim(x) > 0
```

```py
is_scalar(1)               # True
is_scalar(np.array(1))     # True
is_scalar([1])             # False
is_scalar(np.array([1]))   # False
is_scalar('a string')      # False
is_scalar({'key': 10})     # False

is_sequence(1)             # False
is_sequence(np.array(1))   # False
is_sequence([1])           # True
is_sequence(np.array([1])) # True
is_sequence('a string')    # False
is_sequence({'key': 10})   # False
```

Note how both is_scalar and is_sequence call the `str` and `dict` neither a scalar nor a sequence

Answer (score 0):

preds_test[0] is of shape (128,128,1)
Lets check its data type using isinstance() function
isinstance takes 2 arguments.
1st argument is data
2nd argument is data type
isinstance(preds_test[0], np.ndarray) gives Output as True. It means preds_test[0] is an array.