# What is the most pythonic way to use len on a scalar?

Tags: python, iterable, typechecking

I read this question

[python: how to identify if a variable is an array or a scalar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807011/python-how-to-identify-if-a-variable-is-an-array-or-a-scalar)

but when using the following code I get a false on an `np.array` as can be demonstrated below.

```
import collections

isinstance(np.arange(10), collections.Sequence)
# returns false
```

I find it a bit annoying that I can't do `len(1)` and simply get `1`.

The only work around I can think of is a `try except` statement such as the following:

```
a = 1
try:
    print len(a)
except TypeError:
    print 1
```

Is there a more Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: At the *very least* qualify your `except`. Only `TypeError` needs to be caught here. How did you end up with a situation where you need got such a mix of types in the first place however?

Comment: Anything wrong with the second answer in your link, which specifically mentions numpy?

Comment: @ Mark Ranson hm. I think it probably works. I was hoping that someone would say oh sure there is something like np.len(a) which does this kind of thing. It seems there isn't.

Comment: @MartijnPieters well it's due to using `numpy`, `mpmath` or a single number. So the set of types it can be is finite (of course) but still would be nice not to list what happens under each case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters edited the question as per your suggestion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`collections.Sequence` only applies to sequence objects, which are a very specific type of iterable object.  Incidentally, a `numpy.ndarray` (which is returned by `numpy.arange`) is not a sequence.

You need to test for either [`collections.Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Iterable), which represents any iterable object:

```
>>> isinstance([1, 2, 3], collections.Iterable)
True
>> isinstance(np.arange(10), collections.Iterable)
True
>>> isinstance(1, collections.Iterable)
False
>>>
```

or [`collections.Sized`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Sized), which represents any object that works with `len`:

```
>>> isinstance([1, 2, 3], collections.Sized)
True
>>> isinstance(np.arange(10), collections.Sized)
True
>>> isinstance(1, collections.Sized)
False
>>>
```

You can then use a conditional expression or similar to do what you want:

```
print len(a) if isinstance(a, collections.Iterable) else 1

print len(a) if isinstance(a, collections.Sized) else 1
```

For a complete list of the available abstract base classes in the `collections` module, see [Collections Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) in the Python docs.

Comment: If you just want to know whether `len` will work or not, `collections.Sized` would be more general. But it depends what the OP actually wants to do with the objects.

Comment: I think I'll go with `collections.Sized` seems more general. Kind of surprised that this kind of function doesn't already exist in `numpy` or smth similar.

Comment: Better use `collections.abc.Sized` now: `DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.10 it will stop working.`

Answer (score 5):

I'll just throw in another potential option:

```
length = getattr(obj, '__len__', lambda:1)()
```

So get either the `__len__` method from the object, or a function that always returns 1, then call it to get your result.

I wouldn't say it's Pythonic, but avoids an import and exception handling. However, I'd still go with comparing if it's a `collections.Sized` and a conditional statement and put it in a helper function called `len_or_1` or something.

Answer (score 1):

Although this isn't pythonic as it uses numpy here is another neat way to make this work:

```
import numpy as np
a = 1
aSh = np.shape(a)
if len(aSh) == 0:
    print 1
else:
    print max(aSh)
```

which gives a behaviour that should work with scalars, lists and matrices.