# Checking if a variable can be unpacked

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a variable `x`, which is of an unknown data type. I also have some random function `foo`. Now I want to do something along the following lines:

If `x` is a type that can be unpacked using **, such as a dictionary, call `foo(**x)`. Else, if `x` is a type that can be unpacked using *, such as a tuple, call `foo(*x)`. Else, just call `foo(x)`.

Is there an easy way to check whether a type can be unpacked via either ** or *?

What I am currently doing is checking the type of x and executing something like:

```
if type(x) == 'dict':
    foo(**x)
elif type(x) in ['tuple','list', ...]:
    foo(*x)
else:
    foo(x)
```

But the problem is that I don't know the complete list of data types that can actually be unpacked and I'm also not sure if user defined data types can have a method that allows them to be unpacked.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `try`:

```
try:
    foo(**x)
except:
    try:
        foo(*x)
    except:
        foo(x)
```

Its kind of crude, and doesn't distinguish *why* the exception occurred (which might be mitigated by checking the type of exception), but eliminates the need to try and enumerate which types can be called which way.

Comment: Indeed, `except TypeError` is the minimal restriction you should put on that; though that still doesn't tell you whether `**` raised the exception or something within `foo`.

Comment: Cute answer, but what if foo(x) fails too? might Make another try for it ? Since x is unknown right ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's check the errors we receive when doing it badly:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> f(*x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() argument after * must be a sequence, not int
>>> f(**x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() argument after ** must be a mapping, not int
```

Great: so we need a sequence type for `*` and a mappping type for `**`. The rest is fairly straightforward: the [Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) state:

> There are three basic sequence types: lists, tuples, and range objects. Additional sequence types tailored for processing of binary data and text strings are described in dedicated sections.

The fail-safe way to check if a var is a sequence type is:

```
>>> import collections
>>> all(isinstance(x, collections.Sequence) for x in [[], (), 'foo', b'bar', range(3)])
True
```

(see [Python: check if an object is a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937114/python-check-if-an-object-is-a-sequence) for more info)

The mapping type, according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), is a `dict`:

> There is currently only one standard mapping type, the dictionary.

You can check this in the same way, using `isinstance`, which will even take care of derived classes:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> all(isinstance(x, dict) for x in [{}, OrderedDict(), Counter()])
True
```

So you could do as follows:

```
import collections
if isinstance(x, dict):
    foo(**x)
elif isinstance(x, collections.Sequence):
    foo(*x)
else:
    foo(x)
```

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for, but it doesn't seem to work for sets. For example `isinstance(set([1,2,3]),collections.Sequence)` is false. However, `'{},{}'.format(*set([1,2,3]))` unpacks to `'1,2'` just fine. I'm not sure if there are any other exceptions, but there's at least this one.

Comment: set([1,2,3]) unpacks to 1,2 is fine?

Comment: @K.Mao Hmm...you're right, but note that this doesn't really make a lot of sense since `set`'s are not ordered. I'm checking up on this now

Comment: I did a bit of digging around. Maybe `collections.Iterable` could work? You can unpack sets and dictionaries using * (though dictionaries should probably be unpacked using **). And `all(isinstance(x,collections.Iterable) for x in [set(),[],(),{},'foo',b'bar',range(3)])` evaluates to true, whereas `collections.Sequence` fails on sets and dictionaries. However, I do agree that it doesn't make very much sense to unpack sets or dictionaries using *, considering they are not ordered. But for some reason you can do it in Python.

Comment: You're right: for a `dict` it will iterate through keys. I would advise using `Sequence` because those will give you *predictable, ordered* behavior.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
try:
    (lambda **a: None)(**x)
except TypeError:
    try:
        (lambda *a: None)(*x)
    except TypeError:
        # x cannot be unpacked
        foo(x)
    else:
        # x can be unpacked as a list
        foo(*x)
else:
    # x can be unpacked as a dict
    foo(**x)
```

Or you can define some utility functions

```
def is_list_unpackable(obj):
    try:
        (lambda *a: None)(*obj)
    except TypeError:
        return False
    return True

def is_dict_unpackable(obj):
    try:
        (lambda **a: None)(**obj)
    except TypeError:
        return False
    return True

if is_dict_unpackable(x): # type(x) == 'dict'
    foo(**x)
elif is_dict_unpackable(x): # type(x) in ['tuple','list', ...]:
    foo(*x)
else:
    foo(x)
```

(Inspired by Scott Hunter's answer and deceze's comment)