# better for-loop syntax for detecting empty sequences?

Tags: python, syntax, for-loop

Is there a better way to write the following:

```
   row_counter = 0
   for item in iterable_sequence:
      # do stuff with the item

      counter += 1

   if not row_counter:
      # handle the empty-sequence-case
```

Please keep in mind that I can't use len(iterable_sequence) because 1) not all sequences have known lengths; 2) in some cases calling len() may trigger loading of the sequence's items into memory (as the case would be with sql query results).

The reason I ask is that I'm simply curious if there is a way to make above more concise and idiomatic.  What I'm looking for is along the lines of:

```
for item in sequence:
   #process item
*else*:
   #handle the empty sequence case
```

(assuming "else" here worked only on empty sequences, which I know it doesn't)

Comment: a better way to write it - for what purpose?

Comment: to make it more concise and idiomatic looking.  (i'm going to add this to my question)

Comment: An ORM could answer that for you; something like DB-API's `.fetchone()` or `.first()` methods return `None` if the result set is empty (no rows).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-a-variable-is-iterable

Comment: Personally, I find the original code more readable and idiomatic than the answers given.  (A boolean flag variable `is_empty` would also be appropriate.) @mtrw: iter([]) returns an iterator, but is an empty sequence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for item in iterable:
    break
else:
    # handle the empty-sequence-case here
```

Or

```
item = next(iterator, sentinel)
if item is sentinel:
   # handle the empty-sequence-case here
```

In each case one item is consumed if it is present.

---

An example of `empty_adapter()`'s implementation mentioned in the comments:

```
def empty_adaptor(iterable, sentinel=object()):
    it = iter(iterable)
    item = next(it, sentinel)
    if item is sentinel:
       return None # empty
    else:
       def gen():
           yield item
           for i in it:
               yield i
       return gen()
```

You could use it as follows:

```
it = empty_adaptor(some_iter)
if it is not None: 
   for i in it:
       # handle items
else:
   # handle empty case
```

Introducing special case for an empty sequence for a general case seems *wrong*. There should be a better solution for a domain specific problem.

Comment: I need to process all items in the list, not just the first one.  To process the rest of the items, I'll need to set up another for loop, which will make the entire solution even less concise than the original.

Comment: Looks like consuming an item is not an option for the O.P. since h e has to "do stuff" with each item.

Comment: @Dmitry Beransky: if you need to consume all items then you could write an adapter that accepts an iterable as an input and returns `None` if it is empty or yields the same sequence of items as its input. For the implementation you could use the most readable variant among provided in this question so far.

Answer (score 3):

It may be a job for itertools.tee 
You "trigger" the sequence on the verification, but you are left with an untouched copy of the sequence afterwards:

```
from itertools import tee
check, sequence = tee(sequence, 2)

try:
   check.next():
except StopIteration:
   #empty sequence
for item in sequence:
     #do stuff
```

(it's worth nting that `tee` does the "right" thing here: it will load just the first element of the sequence in the moment `check.next()` is executed - and this first elment will remain available in the `sequence`. The remaining items will only be retrieved as part of the `for` loop
Or just keeping it simple:
If you can't use len, you can't check if the sequence has a bool value of True, for the same reasons.

Therefore, your way seens simple enough  - 
another way would be to delete the name "item" before the "for" statement and
check if it exists after the loop:

```
del item
for item in sequence:
    # do stuff
try:
    item
except NameError:
     # sequence is empty.
```

But your code should be used as its more clear than this.

Comment: `del item` will `raise NameError` if the name `item` wasn't already defined.

Comment: Using ``tee`` is probably not the way to go - it will buffer all elements, expecting ``check`` to be iterated as well. For a finite-length iterable, ``list`` may be more efficient, for an infinite-length iterable it will silently leak memory. Checking for ``NameError`` is brilliant, though.

Answer (score 2):

The second example from J.F. Sebastian seems to be the ticket with a while loop.

```
NoItem = object()
myiter = (x for x in range(10))
item = next(myiter, NoItem)
if item is NoItem:
    ...
else:
    while item is not NoItem:
        print item
        item = next(myiter, NoItem)
```

Not the most concise but objectively the clearest... Mud, no?

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't trigger `len()`:

```
def handle_items(items):
    index = -1
    for index, item in enumerate(items):
        print 'processing item #%d: %r' % (index, item)
    # at this point, index will be the offset of the last item,
    # i.e. length of items minus one
    if index == -1:
        print 'there were no items to process'
    print 'done'
    print

# test with an empty generator and two generators of different length:
handle_items(x for x in ())
handle_items(x for x in (1,))
handle_items(x for x in (1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: [10 years later :-)] This is the best answer for modern python.

Answer (score 0):

```
if not iterable_sequence.__length_hint__():
    empty()
else:
    for item in iterable_sequence:
        dostuff()
```

Comment: wouldn't this trigger a call to len()?

Comment: It would trigger a call to len() for sequences that are already evaluated, which is no problem - it wont call `len` on other iterables - because they don't generally have a `len` anyway. However, those iterables will always test as True unless they've specially overloaded that operation (as `xrange` does).