# How to check if a string is a substring of items in a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

How do I search for items that contain the string `'abc'` in the following list?

```
xs = ['abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456']
```

The following checks if `'abc'` is in the list, but does not detect `'abc-123'` and `'abc-456'`:

```
if 'abc' in xs:
```

Comment: To check the opposite (if one string contains one among multiple strings): http://stackoverflow.com/a/6531704/2436175

Comment: If the left parts of entries are unique, consider constructing a dict from the list: [Find an entry in a list based on a partial string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37042291/find-an-entry-in-a-list-based-on-a-partial-string)

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16381580) by Raymond Hettinger (which should rather be an answer to this question).

Answer (score 1363, accepted):

To check for the presence of `'abc'` in any string in the list:

```
xs = ['abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456']

if any("abc" in s for s in xs):
    ...
```

---

To get all the items containing `'abc'`:

```
matching = [s for s in xs if "abc" in s]
```

Comment: I have to check if one item is in an array of 6 elements. Is it quicker to do 6 "if" or is it the same?

Comment: Another way to get all strings containing substring 'abc': `filter(lambda element: 'abc' in element, some_list)`

Comment: But from readability perspective, I would rather put `any("abc" in s for s in some_list)` in another function and say `contains("abc",list)`

Comment: @alldayremix How would I return the index number for that search? `if myitem in myarray: return index_number` or something.

Comment: @p014k: use the `index()` method: `try: return mylist.index(myitem); except ValueError: pass`

Comment: If by any chance `mylist` has a `None` inside it will throw an exception. To fix this: `any(["abc" in s for s in some_list if s])`

Comment: I am solving an excersice in which I search for a string in a list.
Before lookin the above solution, I used: for string in list: if "blabla" in string -> do something! Which did not work...
Then I saw this and tried: if "blabla" is string for string in list: and it it did not work... I HAD to use both the parenthesis and the ANY.. Why? :/

Comment: @midkin: I neither understand what exactly you were trying to do, nor how it went wrong.  You'll probably have more luck by asking a new question (with the "Ask Question" button), copying your exact code, what you would have expected the code to do, and what it actually did.  "Did not work" is completely meaningless unless you define what "works" means in this context, but even then it's better to explain what actually happened instead of saying what didn't.

Comment: In the above code why is ANY needed? I mean I would expect: if "abc" , and not if any "abc"

Comment: A warning: in Python 3, you will need to put brackets around the contents of the generator, otherwise any will return a generator object, which is always True as a condition.
I.e. use `any(['abc' in s for s in some_list])`

Comment: @YuppieNetworking No, you shouldn't add the square brackets, even in Python 3.  The built-in function `any()` always returns a Boolean value in any Python version that supports it.  (Not sure what gave you the idea you need the square brackets.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach Sorry, I was wrong. I got confused since I was using ipython --pylab, where numpy.any is called instead of builtin any

Comment: @YuppieNetworking Ah, that explains it.  Using `from numpy import *` or `--pylab` causes quite a bit confusion due to shadowed built-ins, which is why I tend to avoid it.

Comment: Check multiple substrings in URL: any([substring in "http://www.example.com/?query1=foo?query2=bar" for substring in some_list])

Comment: If you want to compare case insensitive use: `matching = [s for s in some_list if "abc".lower() in s.lower()]`

Comment: Just thought I'd add my two cents. This would have to be modified on a list of lists. Ex:                                                                                                         
    sooners = [(('GO', 'OKLAHOMA'), 'GO TO OKLAHOMA')]; 
    row1 = [row[1] for row in test];
    matching = [s for s in row1 if 'OKLAHOMA' in s];
    print(matching); output: ['GO TO OKLAHOMA']... if you don't define a row, you will get empty brackets [].

Comment: This appears to also match any the characters are otherwise separately present. i.e. a match will be found if some_list has an ["cba-4123"]. Is a small modification possible to make it only match in the correct order?

Comment: @LarryCai The check `"abc" in some_string` will check for presence of `"abc"` as an exact, contiguous substring of `some_string`, so both `"abc" in "cba-4123"` and `"abc" in "a-b-c"` will return `False`. No modification of the code required.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks for confirming, it would appear my code/objects are creating this unintended result due to other reasons then. Will do some further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 238):

Just throwing this out there: if you happen to need to match against more than one string, for example `abc` and `def`, you can combine two comprehensions as follows:

```
matchers = ['abc','def']
matching = [s for s in my_list if any(xs in s for xs in matchers)]
```

Output:

```
['abc-123', 'def-456', 'abc-456']
```

Comment: You could also use `{s for s in my_list for xs in matchers if xs in s}` (note the curly brackets to create a unique set). Might be easier to read, but could be slower if most `s` values will have a match, since your `any` will efficiently stop at the first match.

Comment: AMAZING - in a similar situation I would use pandas str.contains, but with lists this is perfect

Comment: Great, solution. In my case I needed to check if my string (s) had ALL the substrings (xs) from a list (in this case `matchers`).  I just changed `any` for `all` and it did the trick:
`matching = [s for s in my_list if all(xs in s for xs in matchers)]`

Answer (score 107):

Use `filter` to get all the elements that have `'abc'`:

```
>>> xs = ['abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456']
>>> list(filter(lambda x: 'abc' in x, xs))
['abc-123', 'abc-456']
```

One can also use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [x for x in xs if 'abc' in x]
```

Answer (score 103):

If you just need to know if 'abc' is in one of the items, this is the shortest way:

```
if 'abc' in str(my_list):
```

*Note: this assumes 'abc' is an alphanumeric text. Do not use it if 'abc' could be just a special character (i.e. []', ).*

Comment: This would fail if you had a list of ["abc1", "1abc2"] as it would find a match because the string 'abc' would be in the newly created string

Comment: Yes, this is the intended behaviour...  true if any of the items contain 'abc'

Comment: I don't know why all these other people decide to do those convoluted lambda solutions when they don't need to! Nice job @RogerS

Comment: Actually the same question almost answers itself... I just added 3 letters to it.

Comment: It's a nice solution, but if you want to find _the items_ which contain the given string, you will not succeed. Here you find out if _any_ of the items contains the string.

Comment: ['ab', 'c'] has no 'abc' item, but str(['ab', 'c']) will have an 'abc' match.

Comment: @konst54 it will not match... Give it a try on your console so you can see by yourself.

Comment: @RogerS I see. Was not obvious for me, thought it would give a string of concatenated elements, not array structure stringified, sorry. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

Comment: This answer is a little off the mark. Converting the list to a str will result in a string with "[", "]", "'", ",", and " " characters. This could be a problem depending on what you are searching for. Remove the str conversion to search for exact matches in the list.

Comment: Samuel if you remove the 'str' conversion you will only get exact matches... The question asked to find 'abc' in particular, which this solution provides. It generalizes well to any normal text. It will not work if your text is only one of special characters that str adds (i.e. '[], ) but this was not the question asked.

Comment: @RogerS, That's good solution, How can I also print that specific item where 'abc' is found?

Answer (score 19):

This is quite an old question, but I offer this answer because the previous answers do not cope with items in the list that are not strings (or some kind of iterable object). Such items would cause the entire list comprehension to fail with an exception.

To gracefully deal with such items in the list by skipping the non-iterable items, use the following:

```
[el for el in lst if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and (st in el)]
```

then, with such a list:

```
lst = [None, 'abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456', 123]
st = 'abc'
```

you will still get the matching items (`['abc-123', 'abc-456']`)

The test for iterable may not be the best. Got it from here: [In Python, how do I determine if an object is iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-a-variable-is-iterable)

Comment: Wouldn't `[el for el in lst if el and (st in el)]` make more sense in the given example?

Comment: @tinix I don't that will handle non-iterable objects gracefully, will it?

Comment: "given example"


`my_list = ['abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456']`


no need to over complicate it.

Comment: Yes absolutely - the accepted answer is perfectly suitable and my suggestion is more complicated, so feel free to ignore it - I just offered in case someone had the same problem as I had: non-iterable items in such lists are a real-world possibility despite not existing in the given example.

Answer (score 16):

```
x = 'aaa'
L = ['aaa-12', 'bbbaaa', 'cccaa']
res = [y for y in L if x in y]
```

Answer (score 12):

```
for item in my_list:
    if item.find("abc") != -1:
        print item
```

Comment: If you're going to take this approach, I think it's more idiomatic to do `if 'abc' in item` rather using `item.find('abc') == -1`.

Answer (score 10):

```
any('abc' in item for item in mylist)
```

Answer (score 10):

I am new to Python. I got the code below working and made it easy to understand:

```py
my_list = ['abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456']
for item in my_list:
    if 'abc' in item:
       print(item)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`__contains__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) method of Pythons string class.:

```py
a = ['abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456']
for i in a:
    if i.__contains__("abc") :
        print(i, " is containing")
```

Answer (score 4):

I needed the **list indices** that correspond to a match as follows:

```
lst=['abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456']

[n for n, x in enumerate(lst) if 'abc' in x]
```

**output**

```
[0, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get list of data for multiple substrings

you can change it this way

```
some_list = ['abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456']
# select element where "abc" or "ghi" is included
find_1 = "abc"
find_2 = "ghi"
result = [element for element in some_list if find_1 in element or find_2 in element] 
# Output ['abc-123', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist=['abc','def','ghi','abc']

pattern=re.compile(r'abc') 

pattern.findall(mylist)
```

Comment: In Python3.6 this gives an error: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: @AimForClarity Yes.  re.findall in python3.6 expects a string.  An alternative would be by converting the list into a string                            `import re`    
`mylist=['abc','def','ghi','abcff']`  
`my_list_string=''.join(mylist)`  
`string_to_find="abc" `  
`res=re.findall(string_to_find,my_list_string)`  
`print(res)`

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting. Couldnt do proper line breaks for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Adding nan to list, and the below works for me:

```
some_list = ['abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456',np.nan]
any([i for i in [x for x in some_list if str(x) != 'nan'] if "abc" in i])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ['abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456']

for item in my_list:
    if (item.find('abc')) != -1:
        print ('Found at ', item)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a search, which requires you to input a certain value, then it will look for a value from the list which contains your input:

```
my_list = ['abc-123',
        'def-456',
        'ghi-789',
        'abc-456'
        ]

imp = raw_input('Search item: ')

for items in my_list:
    val = items
    if any(imp in val for items in my_list):
        print(items)
```

Try searching for 'abc'.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_dog(new_ls):
    splt = new_ls.split()
    if 'dog' in splt:
        print("True")
    else:
        print('False')


find_dog("Is there a dog here?")
```