# How do I check if words in a string are elements in a list or lists?

Tags: python

```
test_string = ("this is a test")

test_list = [dog, cat, test, is, water]
```

How do I see if 'this' or 'is' or 'a' or 'test' is in test_list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a string contains an element from a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531482/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-an-element-from-a-list-in-python)

Comment: shouldn't test_list = [dog, cat, test, is, water] rather be test_list = ['dog', 'cat', 'test', 'is', 'water']?

Comment: Yeah I was in a hurry I make that mistake often.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up eduard

Answer (score 0):

Use [str.split](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) to split the string and use [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any)  to see if any of the words in the string are in your list:

```
 test_string = ("this is a test")

test_list = ["dog", "cat", "test", "is","water"]
print(any(x in test_list for x in test_string.split()))



In [9]: test_string = ("this is a test")

In [10]: test_string.split()
Out[10]: ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test'] # becomes a list of individual words
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `any` for this

`inlist = any(ele in test_list for ele in test_string.split())`

`inlist` will be True or False, depending on whether or not it's in the list.

Example:

```
>>test_string = ("this is a test")
>>test_list = ['dog', 'cat', 'water']
>>inlist = any(ele in test_string for ele in test_list)
>>print inlist
False

>>test_string = ("this is a test")
>>test_list = ['dog', 'cat', 'is', 'test' 'water']
>>inlist = any(ele in test_string for ele in test_list)
>>print inlist
True
```

Comment: nope, you are iterating over each character not each word

Comment: I'm iterating over each item in the list and checking if it in the string at all.

Comment: try `s="this is a test" print("th" in s)`

Comment: I interpreted OP's question as just wanting to see if any element in the list appears at all, they didn't clarify. If the OP wants to check if a full word matches, you're correct

Comment: I think it is pretty clear that they would want  to match a full word

Comment: Ah, misread them as asking for checking if a work from list is in string, they wanted vice versa. Fixed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63318/discussion-between-parker-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is just whether the set intersection is nonempty.

```
>>> set(test_string.split(' ')).intersection(set(test_list))
set(['test', 'is'])
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is regex, eg

```
import re

# Test string
test_string = 'this is a test'

# Words to be matched
test_list = ['dog', 'cat', 'test', 'is', 'water']

# Container for matching words
yes = []

# Loop through the list of words
for words in test_list:
    match = re.search(words, test_string)
    if match:
        yes.append(words)

# Output results
print str(yes) + ' were matched'

#['test', 'is'] were matched
```