# How to find if part of a list is in str

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to make a censor. Instead of doing

```
if curseword in typed or curseword2 in typed or curseword3 typed:
    print "No cursing! It's not nice!"
```

I want to make it so that I can have a list with all the words in it, and can check if those words are in the list. Note: if you use the "if any..." code, with a while loop, it has too much output to process.

Comment: What does "Code must be compatible with while loops." mean, exactly?

Comment: **@SiHa** What I mean is that if there is a for in that code, it will endlessly spew output and break the entire world. I need it to not have for loops or else that will happen.

Comment: I'm sure that's because you implemented it incorrectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a string contains an element from a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6531482)

Comment: You may get some false positives this way - but it's not as bad as the Clbuttic Mistake

Comment: **@Bhargav Rao** I posted this question because the other question did NOT answer my question. I put this up because my code requires something without any for loops. By putting it on hold, there is now no way for me to get help. So... yeah. Good job.

Comment: So you are saying a `for` loop will spew on endlessly but a `while` loop won't? Usually it's the other way round if anything.

Comment: BTW, it's _not_ a good idea to use `input` as a variable name as that shadows the built-in `input` function, which is confusing to people reading your code and may lead to mysterious bugs.

Comment: @Oughh: You do realise that the answer you have marked as correct is exactly the same as the accepted answer in the duplicate that you say doesn't work?

Comment: **@SiHa**Yes I do. The problem is that it's the least bad, not the most good. I need this code to work with while loops. If you test out that code with a while loop, you get the error "too much output to process". Also to PM my variables in the actual code are not called input.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `any` plus a generator:

```
cursewords = ['javascript', 'php', 'windows']
if any(curseword in input for curseword in cursewords):
    print 'onoes'
```

Alternatively, for a bit more flexibility, a regex (if you want to do stuff like detect uppercase curse words as well):

```
if re.search(r'javascript|php|windows', input, re.IGNORECASE):
    print 'onoes'
```

(If you're new to regex, [the Python docs have got a nice tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html).)

If you just want to ignore case without messing with regexen, you can do that too:

```
# make sure these are all lowercase
cursewords = ['javascript', 'php', 'windows']
input_lower = input.lower()
if any(curseword in input_lower for curseword in cursewords):
    print 'onoes'
```

Comment: About that regex way, use `'|'.join(cursewords)` then we don't need type these words from the list manually :)

Comment: @KevinGuan Probably not a good idea—what if the "curse words" contain regex special chars? Better to just have a single regex, so you can also do stuff like `java(script)?`.

Comment: Usually you should `re.escape` strings before `'|'.join`ing them into a regex.

Comment: @Doorknob冰: Yeah `re.escape()` works as John said. So `re.search(re.escape('|'.join(cursewords)))`.

Comment: @KevinGuan Nope, you want `'|'.join(map(re.escape, cursewords))`. Otherwise you're escaping the `|`s.

Comment: @Doorknob冰 Yes. (checks - I did say "before"!)

Comment: @Doorknob冰: Oops, forgot about that :P

Comment: **@Doorknob冰** The problem with code like yours, though effective without a while loop, is that with a while loop that says  'while True:' a for loop will infinitely give output because of the while loop. How do I fix that?

Comment: @Oughh I'm not sure what you're trying to say. This isn't an infinite loop.

Comment: I am not so good at coding, but what happens is that because of my while loop, for some reason all for loops that I put in become infinite.

Comment: @Oughh I... still have no idea what you're talking about. Perhaps that would be better as a separate question—include *all* of the code necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: **@Doorknob**while True: if something is something: do something else: for blah in blahblah: if something is not something: print 'nope' <<<result is infinite printing of the word 'nope'

Comment: FWIW, `(curseword in input for curseword in cursewords)` is a _generator expression_. In Python, the term "comprehension" usually refers to a _list comprehension_, eg `[curseword in input for curseword in cursewords]`. Of course, passing a generator expression to `any` is much better than passing a list comprehension to `any` (or `all`), since the former can short-circuit, whereas the latter has to build the complete list before it can start testing.

Comment: @PM2Ring Ah, clearly I'm not up to speed with my Python jargon. Thanks for teaching me!

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop on the input and check each word to see if it's in the list of cursewords.

```
cursewordList = ['a','b' ...]

for word in input:
    if word in cursewordList:
          print "No cursing! It's not nice!"
```

Comment: This way has better big-O complexity - if you make cursewordList a `set`.

Answer (score 0):

Using, filter built-in method as well:

```
>>>test = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR']
>>>input = 'TWO'

>>> if filter(lambda s: s in input, test):
    print 'OK'


OK
>>> input = 'FIVE'
>>> 
>>> if filter(lambda s: s in input, test):
    print 'OK'


>>> #nothing printed
```

Comment: The solution works, but it scans every curse word even if it has found one already.