# searching a text file for key words using .split python

Tags: python, file, search, text

I have a text file with chicken, recipe for chicken as line 1 and beef, beef recipe as line 2.

I can search for the beef or chicken recipe if the user only types beef or chicken. But I want to search for beef recipes if the user types in "I would like to search for beef recipes" or chicken....

I am trying to use .split but not quite there. Below is my code.

```
while True:
    food = input ("What food? ")
    file = open("meals.txt", "r")
        line = file.readline()
        data = line.split(",")
        if data[0] == food:
            print(data[1])
    file.close()
```

Comment: if you know that the first word is the keyword you could do something like `if keyword in food:` to check if the keyword is anywhere in the inputted phrase.

Comment: Is the issue how to search the text, or how to get keywords out of the question?

Comment: Use this piece of code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531482/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-an-element-from-a-list-in-python/6531704#6531704 to search if the input phrase has any word that is present in list1 = ['chicken','beef']

Comment: I would suggest  - file = open("meals.txt", "r") this line to make outside loop and examine break condition in loop

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question in an incomplete specification. You must define what is a word (or this is the same what is a separator), or as an alternative if you want to accept the words as substring. Examples: *I want eggs,beef,veal or goose* (sep is comma) or at the opposite *The beefeater wants chicken recipes*

Answer (score 0):

You will want to make the "food" item into a list, and iterate over it.

```
food_type = food.split()
for type in food_type:
    if type == 'beef':
        #do something
    elif type == 'chicken':
        #do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be using elasticsearch for this. However if you want to do string parsing.

```
while True:
food = input ("What food? ")
food_tokens = food.split()
file = open("meals.txt", "r")
    line = file.readline()
    data = line.split(",")
    for food_token in food_tokens:
        if data[0] == food_token:
            print(data[1])
file.close()
```

This checks for words "beef" and "chicken" and if input contains them, then it prints the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need some sort of list of valid search words, in this case `keywords = ['beef', 'chicken']`. Otherwise, if someone were to search for 'a chicken recipe' you might also get a hit on 'recipe' in 'a tasty beef recipe'. Then you find all valid keywords in the user input, and then match the valid ones to the meals:

```
keywords = ['beef', 'chicken']
userinput = input("what food? ")

# generate a list of meals
with open("meals.txt", "r") as file:
  meals = file.readlines()

for word in userinput.split():
  if word in keywords:
    for meal in meals:
      if word in meal:
        # yay found one, store it or something
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```
import re

foodType = re.search('(beef|chicken)', food)
if foodType is None:
    print 'beef or chicken, make your choice.'
else:
    print foodType.group(1) 
    """whatever you meant to do with beef or chicken instead.
       foodType.group(1) is 'chicken' or 'beef'
    """
```

In there if foodType is None, it means your user didn't type chicken or beef, at all. Otherwise foodType.group(1) is set to chicken, or beef, whichever one was entered. I just put a print, but from there you can do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("txt", "r")
all_lines = file.readlines()

while True:
    food = raw_input ("What food? ")
    for line in all_lines:
        data = line.split(',')
        if data[0] == food:
            print "Found %s" % food
            print "data[1] is %s" % data[1]
            break
    else:
        print "Not found %s" % food
```