# TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bool

Tags: python

I'm working with scrapy 1.1 . After extracting entities I get a string that looks like:

```
bob jones | acme, inc | jeff roberts |company, llc
```

I want to get a list of all the companies, so I tried:

```
company_types = ['inc','llc','corp']
entities = str(item.get('entities')).lower
entity_list = entities.split('|')
company_list= [a in entity_list if any(company_types) in a]
```

I'm getting:

```
company_list= [a for a in entity_list if any(company_types) in a]
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bool
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843158/check-if-a-python-list-item-contains-a-string-inside-another-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here:

```
company_list = [a for a in entity_list if any(company_types) in a]
```

Remember that `any()` is just a function which has to return a single value... and the code would check to see if that single value is in `a`, which is not what you want.

```
company_list = [a for a in entity_list if any(t in a for t in company_types)]
```

Basically, the parentheses were in the wrong place.  Kind of.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the information on this page:
[How to check if a string contains an element from a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531482/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-an-element-from-a-list-in-python)

try changing:

```
company_list= [a in entity_list if any(company_types) in a]
```

to

```
company_list = [a in entity_list if any(company in a for company in company_types)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `any` and `all` like that. Those functions return whether if any or all of what you passed them is true, so they return `True` or `False`, not some magic thing you can use with `in`.