# Searching string for potential combinations of substrings

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a `string`, an `array` which contains possible end characters for that string, and a block of text to parse. For example:

```
stringText = "something"
endChars = [",", ".", ";", " "]
textBlock = "This string may contain something;"
```

In a one line `if` statement, I want to check if `textBlock` contains the `stringText` followed by any one of the `endChars`. I'm pretty sure I can do this with the built in `any` function in Python 2.7, but my efforts so far have failed. I have something similar to this:

```
if re.search(stringText + any(endChar in endChars), textBlock, re.IGNORECASE):
    print("Match")
```

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531482/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-an-element-from-a-list-in-python) post, however I'm struggling to apply it to my check above. Any help doing to would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

In addition to the above, is it possible to determine which of the `endChars` was found in the string? Using @SCB's answer below and adapting it, I would expect the following to do exactly that, but it throws an undefined error.

```
stringText = "something"
endChars = [",", ".", ";", " "]
textBlock = "This string may contain something;"

if any((stringText + end).lower() in textBlock.lower() for end in endChars):
    print("Match on " + end)
```

*Expected output:* `Match on ;`

*Actual output* `NameError: name 'end' is not defined`

**UPDATE**
I have arrived at a suitable solution to this problem, at least for my requirements. It's not a one-liner, but it does the job. For completeness, shown below

```
for end in endChars:
    if stringText + end in textBlock:
        print("Match on " + end)
```

Comment: `re.search(r'something[,.; ]$',text,re.I)`

Comment: I'd suggest changing the title (and maybe the example), cause this has confused most people into thinking you're looking for only at the end (hence all the answers with `.endswith()`). But I'm pretty sure that's not what you're going for. I've suggested an edit, (needs to be peer reviewed) but you might want to rephrase it yourself.

Comment: What if I change your example to use `stringText = "may"` or `stringText = "is"`? What results do you want for those?

Comment: @SCB, I'm happy with your change to the title of this post, it certainly makes more sense than mine. I feel the example is fairly clear though (albeit the example `if` statement is nonsense) - what I was looking for was put across, and the majority of suggestions (though not tried all), do what I was after.

Comment: @StefanPochmann, for the `stringText` values provided in your comment, I would expect `Match` to be printed for both. The reason being that 'is ' (including a trailing space) is present, as is 'may ' (including a trailing space).

Comment: Ok then the old title was indeed bad, since you didn't want any "Checking if a string ends"...

Comment: @StefanPochmann Yeah, checking if a string contains _another_ string, which ends in something... title was pretty misleading. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should perform the `any()` as the outmost operation (and in fact, you don't even need regex).

```
if any(stringText + end in textBlock for end in endChars):
    print("Match")
```

To perform case insensitive matching, just use the `.lower()` function on both sides:

```
if any((stringText + end).lower() in textBlock.lower() for end in endChars):
    print("Match")
```

Comment: This seems simple enough and looks like it should do the job, however can this be made case-insensitive?

Comment: Yeah, it could by converting everything to lowercase. I'll add an edit.

Comment: Using your answer is it possible to adapt this to display the item from the `endChars` array which was matched on? I've updated the original question with more information on this.

Comment: The reason you're getting that error you mention above is because the scope of `end` only exists inside the `any()` generator. By the time you get into the `if` statement, it's no longer there. Since this isn't what the original question asked, I'd suggest you open another question with your new requirements.

Answer (score 1):

A non regex solution:

```
stringText = "something"
endChars = [",", ".", ";", " "]
textBlock = "This string may contain something;"
if any((stringText+i in textBlock for i in endChars):
   #condition met
   pass
```

Regex solution:

```
import re
if re.findall('|'.join('{}\{}'.format(stringText, i) for i in endChars), textBlock):
   #condition met
   pass
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `any()` and `map` built-ins:

```
stringText = "something"
endChars = [",", ".", ";", " "]
textBlock = "This string may contain something;"

if any(map(textBlock.endswith, [stringText, *endChars])):
    print("Match")
```

- `[stringText, *endChars]` is the `list` of all possible endings.
- `map()` maps each element of that list to the method `textBlock.endswith()`
- `any()` returns `True` is any of the elements of `map()` is `True`

Answer (score 0):

```
testBlock.endswith(tuple([stringText + endChar for endChar in endChars]))
```