# How To check the validity of password according to input by users

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, passwords

To check the validity of password input by users.

Following are the criteria for checking the password:

1. At least 1 letter between a-z.
2. At least 1 number between 0-9
3. At least 2 letter between A-Z
4. At least 2 character from $#@,. ETC
5. Minimum length of transaction password: 6
6. Maximum length of transaction password: 12

[Answers to this question couldn't clear the problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531482/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-an-element-from-a-list-in-python)

I tried this but it doesn't worked

```
N = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
A = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
S = ['!','@','#','$','%','~','`','^','&','*','(',')','_','+','=','-']

pasw = input('Password: ')
if any((word in pasw for word in N,A,S)):
  print ('OK')
else:
   print ('TRY LATER')
```

Comment: have you tried a regex?

Comment: what is that  ??

Comment: Same Question...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51960351/writing-tests-for-a-python3-password-checker

Comment: a regex is a regular expression, see [here](https://regexr.com/) or [here](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: @mast3rd3mon : thanks,I should understand regex first

Answer (score -1):

The best way is with a regex as suggested, but that is a whole new world if you don't know what one is. I suggest you read up.

But using code you understand it can be done:

```
pasw='PAssword1!!'

S = ['!','@','#','$','%','~','`','^','&','*','(',')','_','+','=','-']
upper,lower,number,special = 0,0,0,0

for n in pasw:
    if n.islower():
        lower=1
    if n.isnumeric():
        number=1
    if n.isupper():
        upper+=1
    if n in S:
        special+=1

if len(pasw) >= 6 and len(pasw) <= 12 and lower > 0 and number > 0 and special > 1 and upper > 1:
    print('OK')
else:
    print('TRY LATER')
```