# How to filter a nested list of URLs?

Tags: python

I am trying to filter a list of URL's based on the words in the URL.

For example, if any part of the URL contains `/thema/` or `/autor/` it should be deleted.

Sample list:

```
p = [['www.sample.de/fl/autor/xxx',
      'www.sample.de/fl/autor/xxx',
      'www.sample.de/fl/autor/xxx',],
      ['www.temp.de/thema/xxx',
      'www.temp.de/thema/xxx',]
    ]
```

My code:

```py
filters = ['/autor/', '/thema/' ]

fil = []
for sbl in p:
    for i in sbl:
        if i in filters:
            break
        fil.append(sbl)
        break
```

However, this does not filter anything.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: The problem could've been reduced just to one line - `if i in filters` - which is a wrong way to [check if a string contains an element from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6531482/7851470). Next time, please, provide a [**minimal** and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `any()` inside a list comprehension there by removing the url if any of the filter is found in it:

```
from itertools import chain

p = [['www.sample.de/fl/autor/xxx',
      'www.sample.de/fl/autor/xxx',
      'www.sample.de/fl/autor/xxx',],
      ['www.temp.de/thema/xxx',
      'www.temp.de/thema/xxx',]
    ]

filters = ['/autor/', '/thema/' ]  
p = [x for x in chain.from_iterable(p) if not any(f in x for f in filters)]

# []
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a flag to do this:

```
p = ['www.sample.de/fl/autor/xxx',
      'www.sample.de/fl/autor/xxx',
      'www.sample.de/fl/autor/xxx',
      'www.temp.de/thema/xxx',
      'www.temp.de/thema/xxx',
     'www.sample.de/fl/autoor/xxx',
     'www.temp.de/theema/xxx',
    ]

filters = ['/autor/', '/thema/' ]

fil = []
for sbl in p:
    flag = False
    for i in filters:
        if i in sbl:
            flag = True
    if not flag:
        fil.append(sbl)
fil
#['www.sample.de/fl/autoor/xxx', 'www.temp.de/theema/xxx']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re


p = ['www.sample.de/fl/autor/xxx',
      'www.sample.de/fl/autor/xxx',
      'www.sample.de/fl/autor/xxx',
      'www.temp.de/thema/xxx',
      'www.temp.de/thema/xxx',
    ]

filters = ['/autor/', '/thema/' ]
pattern = re.compile(r"(\b" + "|".join(filters) + r"\b)")
print([i for i in p if not pattern.search(i)])
```

---

Edit as per comment

```
p = [['www.sample.de/fl/autor/xxx',
      'www.sample.de/fl/autor/xxx',
      'www.sample.de/fl/autor/xxx',],
      ['www.temp.de/thema/xxx',
      'www.temp.de/thema/xxx',]
    ]
filters = ['/autor/', '/thema/' ]
pattern = re.compile(r"(\b" + "|".join(filters) + r"\b)")
print([[j for j in i if not pattern.search(j)] for i in p])
# --> [[], []]
```

Answer (score 1):

With nested lists you need a recursive function:

```
p = [['www.sample.de/fl/autor/xxx',
      'www.sample.de/fl/autor/xxx',
      'www.sample.de/fl/autor/xxx',],
      ['www.temp.de/thema/xxx',
      'www.temp.de/thema/xxx',]
    ]

def remove(lst, forbidden, suppressempty = None):
    newlst = list()
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            nested_lst = remove(item, forbidden, suppressempty)
            if suppressempty and not nested_lst:
                continue
            newlst.append(nested_lst)
        elif any(word in item for word in forbidden):
            continue
        else:
            if suppressempty and not item:
                continue
            newlst.append(item)
    return newlst

new_lst = remove(p, ['/autor/', '/thema/'], False)
print(new_lst)
```

Which (in this case) yields

```
[[], []]
```

Or - with `suppressempty = True`:

```
new_lst = remove(p, ['/autor/', '/thema/'], True)
print(new_lst)
# []
```

The function above can be used with arbitrary deeply nested lists.

Comment: Wow, Good one! I would reverse the condition check and append to `newlst`, just because `continue` does not look nice.