# How can I check an input against a list's elements?

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
list1 = ['A', 'C', 'G', 'T']

a = input("Please enter your gene sequence: ")
```

Let's say the user enter "GTCAACTB". How can I check each letter in a to make sure that it is in `list1` and if not, ask the user to input again? I don't know how to check the entire input against the list.

In brief, I want to check if the sequence of letters from the input are in `list1`. The sequence could one letter or a sequence of 20 letters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a string contains an element from a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531482/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-an-element-from-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
list1 = ['A', 'C', 'G', 'T']

repeat = True
while repeat:
    a = input("Please enter your gene sequence: ")
    repeat = any([char.upper() not in list1 for char in a])
```

This `[char.upper() not in list1 for char in a]` is known as *list comprehension* in Python and allows you to create a new list by iterating over the characters in your string `a`. The value added for each character in `a` is `char.upper() not in list1` which is a boolean value, checking if that character does not exist in `list1`. At the end you should have a new list `[False, True, False]` and using `any()` higher-order function you check if in that list there is any (at least one) True value (i.e., if there is at least one True value it means there is a character in the string that is not in `list1`).

For `a = "ABC"` the list comprehension `[char.upper() not in list1 for char in a]` yields to `[False, True, False]` and `any([False, True, False]) = True`.