# How to use any generators to check a string is part of a list of other strings?

Tags: python, generator, any

I am reading about `any()` in python and I am not sure how to use it.

My case is as follows:
Given two lists of server names, list A and list B, I need to check if any of the names from A matches to B.

I found these two questions that is similar to what I am trying to do:

- [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)
- [How to check if a string contains an element from a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531482/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-an-element-from-a-list-in-python)

But I am not understanding the code of `any()` very well. Is the below what I am supposed to do with the generator?

```
any(X in listA for Y in listB)
```

means 'If any item `X` in `listA` is truthty against each item `Y` in `listB` return true?'

Answer (score 3):

I think that what you really want is to check whether the intersection of set A and set B is non empty.

If you want to follow the `any` route, you want the following expression `any(x in listA for x in listB)`.

The function `any` is basically a function which chains `or`.

```py
any([True,False,True]) // === True or False or True (which is True)
```

The expression `x in listA` is either True if `x` (which is an element of `listB` is also an element of `listA`). `[x in listA for x in listB]` creates a list of booleans (and `(x in listA for x in listB)` creates a generator with the same elements), which tells us which elements of `listB` are in `listA`. If at least one of those booleans is `True` that means that some server names in `listA` are also in `listB`.

Comment: this is not a generator :) need double parenthesis

Comment: They are optional, `x in listA for x in listB` is not a standalone valid Python expression but `(x in listA for x in listB)` is a generator. However, `any(x in listA for x in listB)` works fine, even without the double parenthesis.

Comment: @BingWang: no. You do not need double parens to make a generator, or even single parens if the generator expression is constructed as a argument, as is the case for `any()`. Try this to demonstrate: `def f(g): print(g)` and then call with `f(a in B for a in A)`

Comment: I have removed the optional double parentheses

Comment: It's important to understand that the implementation of `any(iterable)` does not evaluate every item in the iterable before returning, unless all items in the iterable are "false". `any()` will return `True` as soon as it sees the first "true" item if there is one. `any()` does not perform an OR operation on all of the items, it iterates over the iterable and returns as soon as possible. See the documentation for [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?#any).