# How to search if every word in string starts with any of the word in list using python

Tags: python-3.x, string, if-statement

I am trying to filter sentences from my pandas data-frame having 50 million records using keyword search. `If any words in sentence starts with any of these keywords.`

```
WordsToCheck=['hi','she', 'can']
text_string1="my name is handhit and  cannary"
text_string2="she can play!"
```

If I do something like this:

```
if any(key in text_string1 for key in WordsToCheck):
    print(text_string1)
```

I get `False positive` as `handhit` as `hit` in the last part of word.

How can I smartly avoid all such False positives from my result set?
Secondly, is there any faster way to do it in python? I am using `apply` function currently.

I am following this link so that my question is not a duplicate: [How to check if a string contains an element from a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531482/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-an-element-from-a-list-in-python)

Comment: if your only instereated in the start of the string what about `if any(text_string1.startswith(key) for key in WordsToCheck)`

Comment: Not start of string, but start of every word within that string!

Answer (score 1):

If the case is important you can do something like this:

```
def any_word_starts_with_one_of(sentence, keywords):
  for kw in keywords:
    match_words = [word for word in sentence.split(" ") if word.startswith(kw)]
    if match_words:
      return kw
  return None

keywords = ["hi", "she", "can"]
sentences = ["Hi, this is the first sentence", "This is the second"]
for sentence in sentences:
   if any_word_starts_with_one_of(sentence, keywords):
     print(sentence)
```

If case is not important replace line 3 with something like this:

```
match_words = [word for word in sentence.split(" ") if word.lower().startswith(kw.lower())]
```