# Remove multi-word substring from string if substring in list in data frame column

Tags: python, pandas

Asking a follow up question to my question here: [Remove substring from string if substring in list in data frame column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73718949/remove-substring-from-string-if-substring-in-list-in-data-frame-column/73719025#73719025)

I have the following data frame `df1`

```
       string             lists
0      I HAVE A PET DOG   ['fox', 'pet dog', 'cat']
1      there is a cat     ['dog', 'house', 'car']
2      hello EVERYONE     ['hi', 'hello', 'everyone']
3      hi my name is Joe  ['name', 'was', 'is Joe']
```

I'm trying to return a data frame `df2` that looks like this

```
       string             lists                         new_string
0      I HAVE A PET DOG   ['fox', 'pet dog', 'cat']     I HAVE A
1      there is a cat     ['dog', 'house', 'car']       there is a cat
2      hello everyone     ['hi', 'hello', 'everyone']   
3      hi my name is Joe  ['name', 'was', 'is Joe']     hi my
```

The solution I was using does not work for cases where a substring is multiple words, such as `pet dog` or `is Joe`

```
df['new_string'] = df['string'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word.lower() not in df['lists'][df['string'] == x].values[0]]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is roughly similar, but still quite different.

In this case we use `re.sub` over the row axis (`axis=1`):

```
df.apply(lambda row: re.sub("|".join(row["lists"]), "", row["string"], flags=re.I), axis=1)
```

```
              string                  lists      new_string
0   I HAVE A PET DOG    [fox, pet dog, cat]       I HAVE A 
1     there is a cat      [dog, house, car]  there is a cat
2     hello EVERYONE  [hi, hello, everyone]                
3  hi my name is Joe    [name, was, is Joe]         hi my
```

To break it down:

1. `df.apply` with `axis=1` applies a function to each row
2. `re.sub` is the regex variant of `str.replace`
3. We use `"|".join` to make a "|" seperated string, which acts as `or` operator in regex. So it removes one of these words.
4. `flags=re.I` so it ignores case letters.

Note: since we use `apply` over the row axis, this is basically a loop in the background and thus not very optimimized.

Comment: If any of the strings in `row["lists"]` might contain special characters (for example because it is sourced from user input) you need to escape them, like so: `"|".join(re.escape(item) for item in row["lists"])`. Otherwise the regular expression will not work as expected.

Comment: this worked perfectly! I'm working with a pretty large dataset so I might need to think of a different way to format the df to make this more efficient