# Searching for a string in a multidimentional list and appending the sublist containing match to empty list

Tags: python, list, iterator

I have a question that is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843158/check-in-python-if-a-list-item-contains-a-string), but mine concerns multidimentional lists like this:

```
myList = [['abc', 'abc-321'], ['def', '789-abc'], ['xyz', 'xyz-123']]
newList = []
```

I want to search this myList for a certain word/phrase, and if there are matches, the entire sublist to be appended to newList, with a way to control with elements are searched

For example, If I search for the the tern 'abc' in the first and second element of each sublist, newList should be (two matches):

`[['abc', 'abc-321'], ['def', '789-abc']]`

but if only the first element is to be searched, newList should be (only one match):

`[['abc', 'abc-402']]`

How can I do both types of searches in the most efficient way? Please consider this: The list to be searched contains around a thousand sublists and the text to be searched is about 1-2 paragraphs on average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
def foo(myList,key,first=True):
    if first: #First Element Search
        return [x for x in myList if key in x]
    else: #Search Both Element
        return [x for x in myList if key in x or key in x[1]]

>>> foo(myList,'abc',0)
[['abc', 'abc-321']]
>>> foo(myList,'abc',1)
[['abc', 'abc-321'], ['def', '789-abc']]
```

Note: This simply utilized List Comprehension. The only thing to note is the comparison. Comparing two string with `in` will try to match the first string any where in the second string. Comparing a string with a list, it will try to match the first string anywhere in the first element of the string.

A simpler implementation

```
def foo(myList,key,first=True):
    return [x for x in myList if key in x or not first and key in x[1]]

>>> foo(myList,'abc')
[['abc', 'abc-321']]
>>> foo(myList,'abc',first=False)
[['abc', 'abc-321'], ['def', '789-abc']]
>>> foo(myList,'abc',first=True)
[['abc', 'abc-321']]
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. I wonder if there is any significant performance diff between the `if any()` way vs your way

Comment: Usually if there are just two elements I would prefer to use `or` / `and` and if there are more than two elements `any`/`all` would be preferred. When Things are obvious no point of adding an extra level of complexity

Comment: I would strongly recommend making separate functions for the two cases. The functionality isn't really that similar.

Comment: @ofko: `if any()` and `foo()` lead to different results e.g., `foo()` incorrectly returns empty list for `myList = [['abc-1', 'def']]` whereas `if any()` works correctly and matches the item. [Demo](http://ideone.com/Vb505).

Answer (score 1):

or:

```
def bar(L, S):
    return list( v for v in L if any(S in s for s in v) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[lst for lst in myList if any('abc' in s for s in lst)]
```

if only the first element is to be searched:

```
[lst for lst in myList if 'abc' in lst[0]]
```