# Check if list items contains substrings from another list

Tags: python, list

I have a lists:

```
my_list = ['abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456', 'def-111', 'qwe-111']

bad = ['abc', 'def']
```

and want to search for items that contain the string 'abc' and 'def' (and others in bad). How can I do that?

Almost same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843158/check-in-python-if-a-list-item-contains-a-string).

Comment: What exactly have you tried and what is not working?

Comment: What does your current code look like?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you just want a test, join the target list into a string and test each element of `bad` like so:

```
>>> my_list = ['abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456', 'def-111', 'qwe-111']
>>> bad = ['abc', 'def']
>>> [e for e in bad if e in '\n'.join(my_list)]
['abc', 'def']
```

From your question, you can test each element as a sub string against the each element of the other this way:

```
>>> [i for e in bad for i in my_list if e in i]
['abc-123', 'abc-456', 'def-456', 'def-111']
```

It is fast (in comparison to one of the other methods):

```
>>> def f1():
...    [item for item in my_list if any(x in item for x in bad)]
... 
>>> def f2():
...    [i for e in bad for i in my_list if e in i]
... 
>>> timeit.Timer(f1).timeit()
5.062238931655884
>>> timeit.Timer(f2).timeit()
1.35371994972229
```

From your comment, here is how you get the elements that do not match:

```
>>> set(my_list)-{i for e in bad for i in my_list if e in i}
{'ghi-789', 'qwe-111'}
```

Comment: @Alex: Use a set: `set(my_list)-{i for e in bad for i in my_list if e in i}`

Comment: you saved a day for me

Answer (score 13):

```
In [4]: filter(lambda item: any(x in item for x in bad), my_list)
Out[4]: ['abc-123', 'def-456', 'abc-456', 'def-111']
```

or

```
In [13]: [item for item in my_list if any(x in item for x in bad)]
Out[13]: ['abc-123', 'def-456', 'abc-456', 'def-111']
```

Comment: Nice solution. I wish to have output in reverse i.e., need to get items which is not matches.. Ex: [''ghi-789'', "qwe-111"]

Answer (score 2):

```
some_list = ['abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456']
bad = ['abc', 'def']
for s in some_list:
    for item in bad:
       if item in s:
          print 'Found ', s
```

It's simple, works fine and fast( only if your list is not very big.)

Comment: if any(item in s):
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

Comment: It should be `if item in s:` I guess

Answer (score 0):

```
some_list=['abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456']
bad = ['abc', 'def']
for i in range (0,len(bad)):
    if bad[i] in some_list:
        print('Found a bad entry:', bad[i])
```

Comment: While this code snippet may answer the question, it doesn't provide any context to explain how or why. Consider adding a sentence or two to explain your answer.