# Remove regex elements from list

Tags: python, regex, list, parsing

I use python 2.7.
I have data in file 'a':

```
myname1@abc.com;description1
myname2@abc.org;description2
myname3@this_is_ok.ok;description3
myname5@qwe.in;description4
myname4@qwe.org;description5
abc@ok.ok;description7
```

I read this file like:

```
with open('a', 'r') as f:
    data = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
```

i have a list named bad:

```
bad = ['abc', 'qwe'] # could be more than 20 elements
```

Now i'm trying to remove all lines with 'abc' and 'qwe' after @ and write the rest to the newfile.
So in newfile should be only 2 lines:

```
myname3@this_is_ok.ok;description3
abc@ok.ok;description7
```

I've been tryin to use regexp (.*?)@(.*?);(.*) to get groups, but i don't know what to do next.

Advice me, please!

Comment: Show us the code you've tried.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328940/check-if-list-item-contains-items-from-another-list/11329368#11329368

Comment: Tisho, i've been there. But the problem is that i have to use regex to make groups for checking. Or maybe theres other way that i don't know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
bad = ['abc', 'qwe']

with open('a') as f:
    print [line.strip() 
           for line in f
           if not re.search('|'.join(bad), line.partition('@')[2]]
```

This solution works as long as bad only contains normal characters eg. letters, numbers, underscores but nothing that interferes with the regex expression like `'a|b'` as @phihag pointed out.

Comment: This fails for bad values of `bad`, for example `['a|b']`.

Comment: @phihag Agreed I will note that.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a non-regex solution:

```
bad = set(['abc', 'qwe'])

with open('a', 'r') as f:
    data = [line.strip() for line in f if line.split('@')[1].split('.')[0] in bad]
```

Answer (score 0):

The regexp `.?` matches either no or one character. You want `.*?`, which is a lazy match of multiple characters:

```
import re
bad = ['abc', 'qwe']

filterf = re.compile('(.*?)@(?!' + '|'.join(map(re.escape, bad)) + ')').match
with open('a') as inf, open('newfile', 'w') as outf:
    outf.writelines(filter(filterf, inf))
```

Comment: `'(.*?)@(?!%s)' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, bad)`

Answer (score 0):

I have used regular expression to remove lines which contains @abc or @qwe. Not sure if it is the right method

```
import re
with open('testFile.txt', 'r') as f:
     data = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines() if re.match(r'.*@([^abc|qwe]+)\..*;.*',x)]

print data
```

Now the data will have lines which does not have '@abc' and '@qwe'

Or use

```
data = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines() if re.search(r'.*@(?!abc|qwe)',x)]
```

Based on astynax 's suggestion...