# Most pythonic way to select at random an element in a list with conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, conditional-statements

I have two list:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
list2 = [1, 4, 5]
```

I want to select an element from `list1` but it shouldn't belongs to `list2`.

I have a solution using a while loop but I would like to have a one liner more pythonic and elegant.

Comment: Try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328940/check-if-list-item-contains-items-from-another-list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your elements are unique you can use the set difference. (Convert list1 to a set and remove the elements from list2). Then draw a random sample.

```
random.choice(list(set(list1).difference(list2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[item for item in list1 if not in list2]
```

To make it a bit faster(because lookup in set faster than in list):

```
list2_items = set(list2)
[item for item in list1 if not in list2_items]
```

or with filter function(you will get a generator object in Python3

```
filter(lambda item: item not in list2, list1)
```

Converting list2 to set will also speed up filtering here.

To get more information read about [list comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk).

Update: it seems that I missed a point about one random value. Well, you still can use list comprehensions, but use `random.choice` as was mentioned before:

```
import random
random.choice([item for item in list1 if not in list2_items])
```

It will filter choices and then get one randomly. @zeehio response looks like better solution.

Comment: This doesn’t address the random choice.

Comment: Yep, thanks for pointing out. I missed question tags and misunderstand it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import itertools

next(item for item in (random.choice(list1) for _ in itertools.count()) if item not in list2)
```

That's equivalent to:

```
while True:
    item = random.choice(list1)
    if item not in list2:
        break
```

Comment: Not wrong, but something that could require an unbounded number of iterations feels off.

Comment: @chepner That's right, but `set` approaches might be wrong because they require hashable values **and** discard duplicates (thereby possibly skewing probilities). Maybe a check that some elements remain would remain in `list1` would be good but otherwise it's hard to have a "one-to-rule-them-all" approach. And in this case it rarely needs more than 2 tries and it's `O(1)` whereas the `set`-approaches are `O(n)` with a quite high constant factor.

Comment: If the probability of choosing an element that appears in `list2` is high, it is probably worth the effort to filter `list1` *before* calling `random.choice`.

Comment: That's right. For long iterables containing hashable values `set` is definetly the better choice.

Comment: Beware the infinite loop when nothing meets the criteria

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to utilize `set`s like so:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
list2 = [1, 4, 5]

import random

print(random.choice([x for x in set(list1).difference(list2)]))  # kudos @chepner
```

That way we randomly draw from `set(list1) - set(list2)`: elements in `list1` but not in `list2`. This approach also scales well as lists 1 & 2 become large.

---

As @MSeifert noticed, the conversion of `list1` to `set` will remove any duplicate elements that might be present in `list1` thus altering the probabilities. If `list1` might contain duplicate elements in the general case you might want to do this instead:

```
print(random.choice([x for x in list1 if x not in list2]))
```

Comment: Use `set(list1).difference(list2)`, and you won't need to construct an explicit second set. `difference` akes any iterable as an argument, not just a set.

Comment: @chepner then you probably mean `set(list1).difference(list2)`, right?

Comment: `set2`, `list2`, whatever :) Thanks.

Comment: Also important to note that this will discard any duplicates in `list1` (not only those that are present in `list2`) and therefore skew the probabilities.

Answer (score -1):

without importing random library:

```
print((list(set(list1) - set(list2))).pop())
```

inside pop() you can give the index of the element you want to select,it will pop out that element
example : for selecting list of index 1(from new list) ,`((list(set(list1) - set(list2))).pop(1))`

Here this `(list(set(list1) - set(list2))` code will create a new list which contains only list with items from the first list which aren't present in the second one,