# Why is my RegEx code replacing some strings, but not others?

Tags: python, regex

I have abstracts of academic articles. Sometimes, the abstract will contain lines like "PurposeThis article explores...." or "Design/methodology/approachThe design of our study....". I call terms like "Purpose" and "Design/methodology/approach" labels. I want the string to look like this: [label][:][space]. For example: "Purpose: This article explores...."

The code below gets me the result I want when the original string has a space between the label and the text (e.g. "Purpose This article explores....". But I don't understand why it also doesn't work when there is no space. May I ask what I need to do to the code below so that the labels are formatted the way I want, even when the original text has no space between the label and the text? Note that I imported re.sub.

```
def clean_abstract(my_abstract):
    labels = ['Purpose', 'Design/methodology/approach', 'Methodology/Approach', 'Methodology/approach' 'Findings', 'Research limitations/implications', 'Research limitations/Implications' 'Practical implications', 'Social implications', 'Originality/value']
    for i in labels:
        cleaned_abstract = sub(i, i + ': ', cleaned_abstract)
    return cleaned_abstract
```

Comment: [`(?<=[a-z]) ?(?=[A-Z])`](https://regex101.com/r/ARXhg6/1)?

Comment: Thank you, but this would return a larger set of matches than the labels being followed by an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Code

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/Fq63iL)

```
labels = ['Purpose', 'Design/methodology/approach', 'Methodology/Approach', 'Methodology/approach' 'Findings', 'Research limitations/implications', 'Research limitations/Implications' 'Practical implications', 'Social implications', 'Originality/value']
strings = ['PurposeThis article explores....', 'Design/methodology/approachThe design of our study....']
print [l + ": " + s.split(l)[1].lstrip() for l in labels for s in strings if l in s]
```

---

### Results

```
[
    'Purpose: This article explores....',
    'Design/methodology/approach: The design of our study....'
]
```

---

### Explanation

Using the logic from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11329522/3600709) post.

- `print []` returns a list of results
- `l + ": " + s.split(l)[1].lstrip()` creates our strings

  - `l` is explained below
  - `:` literally
  - `s.split(l).lstrip()` Split `s` on `l` and remove any whitespace from the left side of the string
- `for l in labels` Loops over `labels` setting `l` to the value upon each iteration
- `for s in strings` Loops over `strings` setting `s` to the value upon each iteration
- `if l in s` If `l` is found in `s`

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate this, and your explanation.