# How do I check if a list of strings is in another list of strings?

Tags: python

Example

```
description = ['This is a random sentence. I like to travel and stuff','Hello world', 'Things on my bucket list, travel']

my_list = ['travel','fire']
```

I would like to check if ANY of the words on my_list is in description, if so don't do anything. If my_list is not in description I would like to return the string 'Keywords not found'.

How would I go about writing this code?

Comment: Does "the usual way" help you?

Comment: Will your words in `my_list` contain phrases?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check list of words in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271478/check-list-of-words-in-another-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if list item contains items from another list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11328940)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a python list item contains a string inside another string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4843158)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `all` with a double list comprehension:

```
description = ['This is a random sentence. I like to travel and stuff','Hello world', 'Things on my bucket list, travel']
my_list = ['travel','fire']
def response():
   return "found" if any(i in b for i in my_list for b in description) else "Keywords not found"
```

Answer (score 1):

Save words in a set and check whether a word in `my_list` is in the set. This **only** works when there is no phrases in `my_list`. i.e. all words in `my_list` is a unigram.

```
description = ['This is a random sentence. I like to travel and stuff','Hello world', 'Things on my bucket list, travel']
my_list = ['travel','fire']
set_words_in_description = set()
for s in description:  
    # add new words in set_words_in_description
    set_words_in_description.update(set(w for w in s.split()))
```

Using `isdisjoint`

```
def find_word_method_disjoint(my_list, set_words_in_description):
    # check if my_list is disjoint with set_wrods_in_description
    return not set_words_in_description.isdisjoint(my_list)

%timeit find_word_method_disjoint(my_list, set_words_in_description)
189 ns ± 1.53 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

%timeit response()  # function given by the accepted answer.
572 ns ± 9.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to extract all the words from the sentences in `description`, and check if any of the words from `my_list` exist in it:

```
import re

def find_words(words, text):
    desc_words = re.findall(r'[^\s,.]+', "".join(text))

    for word in words:
        if word in desc_words:
            return "found"

    return "Keywords not found"
```

Which outputs:

```
>>> description = ['This is a random sentence. I like to travel and stuff','Hello world', 'Things on my bucket list, travel']
>>> my_list = ['travel','fire']
>>> find_words(my_list, description)
found
```

Or you could use this `set()` approach:

```
def find_words(words, text):
    return "found" if set(words).intersection(re.findall(r'[^\s,.]+', "".join(text))) else "Keywords not found"
```

**Note:** You will have to update your regular expression if you come across sentences with different punctuation other than `,.`.

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul Yeah unfortunately. I don't understand downvoters who don't comment.

Comment: its happens , no worries bro chill we can't change their behaviour :)

Comment: Yeah, I upvoted the other answers because It looks silly to have all the answers downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try set something like this ?

```
description = ['This is a random sentence. I like to travel and stuff','Hello world', 'Things on my bucket list, travel']

my_list = ['travel','fire']

flat=[k for i in description for k in i.split()]


print(any({i}.issubset(set(flat))for i in my_list))
```

output:

```
True
```