# Check if substring is in a list of strings?

Tags: python, string, list

I have found some answers to this question before, but they seem to be obsolete for the current Python versions (or at least they don't work for me).

I want to check if a substring is contained in a list of strings. I only need the boolean result.

I found this solution:

```
word_to_check = 'or'
wordlist = ['yellow','orange','red']

result = any(word_to_check in word for word in worldlist)
```

From this code I would expect to get a `True` value. If the word was "der", then the output should be `False`.

However, the result is a generator function, and I can't find a way to get the `True` value.

Any idea?

Comment: The code you posted works fine (except for `wordlist`/`worldlist`). I'm guessing you forgot the `any()` call when you tried it before.

Comment: I missed that you already used `any`.

Comment: Taking a look at your code and comments, I think the problem is the "any" function I am using. It is probably the any function in the numpy module. So the solution would be to use the built-in function instead, but any idea on how to do this once the numpy module has been imported?

Comment: @DSM, it does.  Just tried it on Python 3.3.

Comment: @DSM np.any(a for a in b) returns a generator

Comment: @MarkTolonen, askewchan: I'm looking at a bool right now, so something must have changed between 1.6.2 and 1.7+.

Comment: You guys were right, with the built-in function works perfectly and the problem is the numpy one. The only problem with Mark's suggestion is that working within "ipython --pylab" imports numpy directly, so Ashwini solution fits perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This problem comes up for me all the time when using `ipython --pylab`, which "helpfully" imports * from numpy for you. In that case you can directly use `__builtin__.any` without having to import `__builtin__` like in Ashwini's answer, since `__builtin__` shows up in interactive shells automatically. Also @DSM: apparently the behavior of `numpy.any` changed (for the worse) in 1.7.

Comment: @DSM, I'm using a 64-bit unofficial numpy 1.7.1 from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/, so that could also be the issue.

Comment: Also, see the new answer below that shows a much faster alternative approach by combining the words into a single string.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can import `any` from `__builtin__` in case it was replaced by some other `any`:

```
>>> from  __builtin__ import any as b_any
>>> lst = ['yellow', 'orange', 'red']
>>> word = "or"
>>> b_any(word in x for x in lst)
True
```

Note that in Python 3 `__builtin__` has been renamed to `builtins`.

Comment: You can work around the issue with `numpy.any` if a list comp is used instead of a generator: `np.any([word in x for x in lis])`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen `np.any` is going to be slow then as it generates the whole list first.

Comment: Relatively slower yes, noticeably slower...only the OP can say, but not for his example :)

Answer (score 70):

### Posted code

The OP's posted code using *any()* is correct and should work.  The spelling of "worldlist" needs to be fixed though.

### Alternate approach with str.join()

That said, there is a simple and fast solution to be had by using the substring search on a single combined string:

```
>>> wordlist = ['yellow','orange','red']
>>> combined = '\t'.join(wordlist)

>>> 'or' in combined
True
>>> 'der' in combined
False
```

For short wordlists, this is several times faster than the approach using *any*.

And if the *combined* string can be precomputed before the search, the in-operator search will always beat the *any* approach even for large wordlists.

### Alternate approach with sets

The O(n) search speed can be reduced to O(1) if a substring set is precomputed in advance and if we don't mind using more memory.

Precomputed step:

```
from itertools import combinations

def substrings(word):
    for i, j in combinations(range(len(word) + 1), 2):
        yield word[i : j]

wordlist = ['yellow','orange','red']
word_set = set().union(*map(substrings, wordlist))
```

Fast O(1) search step:

```
>>> 'or' in word_set
True
>>> 'der' in word_set
False
```

Comment: This is by far the most useful and simple solution in my opinion. It can also be shortened to one line: `'or' in '\t'.join(wordlist)`

Comment: Much faster than going through the list and using 'in' expression on each item

Comment: why use '\t' instead of ' '?

Comment: @NiharKarve Because the string being searched for is more likely to contain '?' than '\t'

Comment: @Raymond Although I do agree that the join method is perhaps clearer, it is **not** faster than using `any(<generator>)`. At best, it is the same speed (when the substring is not in the list). If the word exists in the list, `any` will short circuit and will not check the remainder of the list. For very large lists, this can be several orders of magnitude faster than joining.

Comment: @mjp The one liner is nice if the wordlist is only done once; otherwise, it is best to precompute the *join()* step so that recurring searches only use the in-operator.  Also, it reads little bit better as two separate steps :-)

Comment: @tonysepia Any separator can be used as long it doesn't occur in the wordlist.  A '\t' tab  is a safe choice.  A space will work most of the time unless cases like "de facto" and "de jure" are treated as word units.

Answer (score 19):

You could use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) instead:

```
colors = ['yellow', 'orange', 'red'] 
search = "or"

result = next((True for color in colors if search in color), False)

print(result) # True
```

To show the string that contains the substring:

```
colors = ['yellow', 'orange', 'red'] 
search = "or"

result = [color for color in colors if search in color]  

print(result) # Orange
```

Comment: That looks like a great way to find the objects with the substring, and could be used also for the True/False objective checking the length of the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

Also if someone wants to check if any of the values of a dictionary exists as a substring in a list of strings, can use this:

```
list_a = [
    'Copy of snap-009ecf9feb43d902b from us-west-2',
    'Copy of snap-0fe999422014504b6 from us-west-2',
    'Copy of snap-0fe999422014cscx504b6 from us-west-2',
    'Copy of snap-0fe999422sdad014504b6 from us-west-2'
]
dict_b = {
    '/dev/xvda': 'snap-0fe999422014504b6',
    '/dev/xvdsdsa': 'snap-sdvcsdvsdvs'
}

for b1 in dict_b.itervalues():
    result = next( ("found" for a1 in a if b1 in a1), "not found")
    print result
```

It prints

```
not found
found
```