# Remove string from list if from substring list

Tags: python, string, list, numpy, substring

I was wondering what's the most pythonic way to:

Having a list of strings and a list of substrings remove the elements of string list that contains any of the substring list.

```
list_dirs = ('C:\\foo\\bar\\hello.txt', 'C:\\bar\\foo\\.world.txt', 'C:\\foo\\bar\\yellow.txt')

unwanted_files = ('hello.txt', 'yellow.txt)
```

Desired output:

```
list_dirs = (C:\\bar\\foo\.world.txt')
```

I have tried to implement similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380326/check-if-substring-is-in-a-list-of-strings-in-python), but I'm still struggling making the removal and extend that particular implementation to a list.

So far I have done this:

```
for i in arange(0, len(list_dirs)):
    if 'hello.txt' in list_dirs[i]:
        list_dirs.remove(list_dirs[i])
```

This works but probably it's not the more cleaner way and more importantly it does not support a list, if I want remove hello.txt or yellow.txt I would have to use a or. Thanks.

Comment: @PM 2Ring Yes I was using numpy. arange is similar to range

Comment: It's not safe to modify a collection that you're iterating over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`list comprehensions`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> [l for l in list_dirs if l.split('\\')[-1] not in unwanted_files]
['C:\\bar\\foo\\.world.txt']
```

Use `split` to get filename

```
>>> [l.split('\\')[-1] for l in list_dirs]
['hello.txt', '.world.txt', 'yellow.txt']
```

Comment: Looking a little closer right now. Do this implementation required the correct filename of unwanted files or just a substring? I tested and it seems that required all the correct filename

Comment: Any chance we can modify this to be a substring of the correct filename?

Comment: `l.split('\\')[-1]` in my answer is the substring of the correct filename. see my edit

Comment: Sorry I probably explain me wrong. Imagine this case: 'world.txt' and 'word.txt~'. If I place 'wo' in the unwanted files, I would like to remove both

Comment: @dudas: If you need that full substring detection capability, you should say so in the question! To do that requires a different strategy than Michael9's solution: it needs a double loop.

Comment: @PM 2Ring That idea was born along with this discussion, that's why I didn't put that in first place. Im wondering if anyone can extend the implementation to the substring of the unwated_file names

Comment: @dudas: In that case, maybe you should ask a new question, with appropriate example input.

Comment: @dudas as PM 2Ring said you should ask another question

Answer (score 1):

you also could use a filter function with lambda

```
print filter(lambda x: x.split('\\')[-1] not in unwanted_files, list_dirs)
#['C:\\bar\\foo\\.world.txt']
```

or if you don't mind to import `os` (imo this is cleaner then splitting the string)

```
print filter(lambda x: os.path.basename(x) not in unwanted_files, list_dirs)
```

In a list comprehension it would look like this

```
[l for l in list_dirs if os.path.basename(l) not in unwanted_files]
```