# Python: test if any string in a list contains a given text

Tags: python, string, iterator

I have to test if a list of strings includes at least one element containing a given text (and the text contains quotes).
Is it possible in a compact way without defining a new function?

E.g.

```
# Text to find
text = """This is a text containing 'quotes' and "doublequotes""""

# List to test
test_strings = [
    "This is a text",
    """Wow! This is a text containing 'quotes' and "doublequotes"!!!"""
]
```

Obviously I can use for loops to do that, but I was looking for something to be run in one line but still readable.

Comment: [Check if substring is in a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16380326/1324033).

Comment: Yes! I wasn't able to find it myself!

Answer (score -1):

I don't feel the quotes should make any difference, but you can just do

```
strings_with_text = [s for s in test_strings if text in s]
```