# How to get partial match of a substring in a list of string?

Tags: python

I have a list of items like `gmail, google, outlook` and another list with mx records of a domain like `mail.protection.outlook.com, gmail-smtp.google.com` etc. I wanted to see if the second list contains any word from the first list (even partial matches as it contains dot and hyphen). How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is practically a duplicate of [Check if substring is in a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16380326/4518341), you just need to add a loop over the first list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if substring is in a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380326/check-if-substring-is-in-a-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "in" operator like so:

```
fullstr = "stackoverflow"
substr = "over"

if substr in fullstr:
    print "found!"
else:
    print "not found!"
```

Comment: But how do you do it with lists? Look at [Check if substring is in a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16380326/4518341)

Comment: just iterate through the list, check each string in the list and execute the above code, if its found, you can execute some code/break out and execute what you want to do with that information

Comment: ```for I in range(list_name)```

Answer (score 0):

```
test_list = ["ab", "ba","abc","acb","bac"]
substr = "ab"
res = [i for i in test_list if substr in i]
```