# Find list index of list items within other list items

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a list of long strings and I'd like to get the indexes of the list elements that match a substring of strings in another list. Checking if a list item contains a a single string inside a list is easy to do with list comprehensions, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843158/check-if-a-python-list-item-contains-a-string-inside-another-string?rq=1):

```
my_list = ['abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456']
thing_to_find = "abc"
matching = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if thing_to_find in x]
```

However, I'd like to check not only if `"abc"` is in `x`, but if any strings in another list are in the list, like so:

```
my_list = ['abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456']
things_to_find = ['abc', 'def']
```

This obviously doesn't work (but it would be really cool if it did):

```
matching = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if things_to_find in x]
```

I can find the list indexes if I run commands individually, but it's tedious and horrible:

```
print([i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if 'abc' in x])
# [0, 3]
print([i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if 'def' in x])
# [1]
```

What's the best way to find the indexes of all instances where elements from one list are found in another list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the `any()` function here:

```
matching = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if any(thing in x for thing in things_to_find)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> my_list = ['abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456']
>>> things_to_find = ['abc', 'def']
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if any(thing in x for thing in things_to_find)]
[0, 1, 3]
```

Comment: This has quadratic performance - good for short `things_to_find`, poor for longer such lists.

Comment: @Marcin: to avoid that, you'd need to use a more efficient data structure that support searching for prefixes, or requires the input string to be split.

Comment: Like, say a compiled regex? Still, +1

Comment: The actual `things_to_find` list has about 50 elements. With `timeit`, the `any(in)` solution takes 1.83 seconds, while the regex version takes 10.4. At what point will the regex be faster and more efficient?

Comment: That depends on the regular expression and how the distribution of matches; `any()` exits early so if most of your matches are early in the `things_to_find` list it'll work fast, but if most of your text does *not* have a match a good regular expression pattern could be faster.

Comment: @Andrew Note that 50 is not large. Thousands is large. Just as `any` can work better than worst-case when `things_to_find` is sorted in order of likelihood of a match, regex solutions will work better when the items in `things_to_find` are similar to each other.

Comment: @Andrew: Your regular expression uses `.*` wildcards, introducing backtracking. They are not needed however. Remove those and the expression will already perform much better.

Comment: @Andrew You're including compilation time for the regexes. That's only legitimate if you change the `things_to_find` list every time you search `my_list`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The leading `.*` is necessary if the things to find are not guaranteed to be prefixes.

Comment: True. I'm still new to `timeit` :)

Comment: After testing on my actual data, the `any(in)` solution works best. But @Marcin's regex thing is fantastic too. If I could accept both, I would :)

Comment: @Andrew kind of you to say.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like?:

```
my_list = ['abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456']
things_to_find = ['abc', 'def']
for n, e in enumerate(my_list):
    for m in things_to_find:
        if m in e:
            print '%s is in %s at %s' % (m, e, n)
```

Output:

```
abc is in abc-123 at 0
def is in def-456 at 1
abc is in abc-456 at 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close:

```
matching = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) for keyword in things_to_find if keyword in x]
```

which gives `[0,1,3]`.

You need to iterate through the `things_to_find` list as well, and see if the `keyword` is in `x`.

Comment: -1 because `any` would be more readable, idiomatic, and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a little slow, but why not try:

```
my_list = ['abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456']
things_to_find = ['abc', 'def']
for thing_to_find in things_to_find:
    matching = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if thing_to_find in x]
```

Comment: I like how this could easily make a dict of things to occurrences with this. +1

Answer (score 1):

Build a regex, then test each list element against that:

```
import re
#must use search, not match because no wildcards, unless only looking for prefixes
regex = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(interest) for interest in things_to_find))
```

Don't rebuild the regex every time you do the search - only rebuild when `things_to_find` changes.

I suspect you don't want the indices, but the elements:

```
[x for x in my_list if regex.search(x)]
```

Or, if you really do want the indices:

```
[i for i,x in enumerate(my_list) if regex.search(x)]
```

This will likely perform better than an `any(in)` solution (which is quadratic) for large `things_to_find` lists, but will be overkill for short lists. You'll also see more of a gain where the things in `things_to_find` are similar; and less of a gain if you can sort `things_to_find` such that more likely matches occur first, and if matches are likely.

Comment: You do not need to add `.*` here. Use `regex.search()` instead and avoid the backtracking. You also want to use `re.escape()` on `interest` to avoid enabling potential regular expression metacharacters in the things of interest.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ['abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456']
things_to_find = ['abc', 'def']
matching = [[i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if y in x]for y in things_to_find]
```