# Finding indices of items from a list in another list even if they repeat

Tags: python

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18211963/5553319) works very well for finding indices of items from a list in another list, but the problem with it is, it only gives them once. However, I would like my list of indices to have the same length as the searched for list.
Here is an example:

```
thelist = ['A','B','C','D','E'] # the list whose indices I want
Mylist = ['B','C','B','E'] # my list of values that I am searching in the other list
ilist = [i for i, x in enumerate(thelist) if any(thing in x for thing in Mylist)]
```

With this solution, `ilist = [1,2,4]` but what I want is `ilist = [1,2,1,4]` so that `len(ilist) = len(Mylist)`. It leaves out the index that has already been found, but if my items repeat in the list, it will not give me the duplicates.

Comment: Are you looking for substrings like that question was, or just exact matches?

Comment: at the moment exact matches are fine, but a substring seems more robust

Comment: That sounds kind of suspect. What’s the actual purpose? (Lots of mistakes happen under the guise of robustness.)

Comment: true, I'll be cautious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
thelist = ['A','B','C','D','E']
Mylist = ['B','C','B','E']
ilist = [thelist.index(x) for x in Mylist]

print(ilist)  # [1, 2, 1, 4]
```

Basically, "for each element of `Mylist`, get its position in `thelist`."

This assumes that every element in `Mylist` exists in `thelist`. If the element occurs in `thelist` more than once, it takes the first location.

**UPDATE**

For substrings:

```
thelist = ['A','boB','C','D','E']
Mylist = ['B','C','B','E']
ilist = [next(i for i, y in enumerate(thelist) if x in y) for x in Mylist]

print(ilist)  # [1, 2, 1, 4]
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here's a version that does substrings in the other direction using the example in the comments below:

```
thelist = ['A','B','C','D','E']
Mylist = ['Boo','Cup','Bee','Eerr','Cool','Aah']

ilist = [next(i for i, y in enumerate(thelist) if y in x) for x in Mylist]

print(ilist)  # [1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 0]
```

Comment: Oh I see, got the original question wrong here with the substrings, I am looking for the opposite - suppose `thelist = ['A','B','C','D','E']` and `Mylist = ['Boo','Cup','Bee','Eerr','Cool','Aah']` and the desired output would be `[1,2,1,4,2,0]`

Comment: Then just change `if x in y` to `if y in x`.

Answer (score 1):

Below code would work

```
ilist = [ theList.index(i) for i in MyList ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a reverse lookup from strings to indices:

```
string_indices = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(thelist)}
ilist = [string_indices[c] for c in Mylist]
```

This avoids the quadratic behaviour of repeated `.index()` lookups.

Answer (score 0):

If you data can be implicitly converted to ndarray, as your example implies, you could use [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) (disclaimer: I am its author), to perform this kind of operation in an efficient (fully vectorized and NlogN) manner.

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
ilist = npi.indices(thelist, Mylist)
```

npi.indices is essentially the array-generalization of list.index. Also, it has a kwarg to give you control over how to deal with missing values and such.