# NameError when searching for substring in Python list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a list:

```
mylist = ['item 101', 'element 202', 'string 303', 'member 404']
```

I want to identify the three digits associated with 'item', but 'item' is not always in the same position, so I cannot use `mylist[0]`.

I looked at the accepted answer in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843158/check-if-a-python-list-item-contains-a-string-inside-another-string), and tried the following:

```
if any('item' in s for s in mylist):
    print(s)
```

I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 's' is not defined
```

In researched that error, but I haven't been able to find any examples/solutions that fit this particular situation.

Comment: The reason you are getting this error is because `s` is only in scope for the life of that generator expression. Once it is exhausted and `any()` returns it's value `s` will no longer be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is happening because you are trying to look into s before s has been defined in the for loop. A simple work around for that would be to break the statements apart into:

`for s in mylist:
    if 'item' in s:
       print(s)`

Answer (score 3):

The simpler way to approach your problem is by using a list comprehension

```
>>> mylist = ['item 101', 'element 202', 'string 303', 'member 404']
>>> [s for s in mylist if 'item' in s]
['item 101']
```

If you are assured that there is only one element like that in the list then you can aswell use list-indexes

```
>>> [s for s in mylist if 'item' in s][0]
'item 101'
```

Or a better way would be to use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) and a gen-exp.

```
>>> next(s for s in mylist if 'item' in s)
'item 101'
```

And to get the 3 digits from the string `'item 101'` you can do `mystr[5:9]` where `mystr` has the value `'item 101'`

Comment: If you're assured there is only one it's best to use `next(s for s in mylist if 'item' in s)`.

Comment: Aha! @orlp Yes. Thanks for that, I will add it to the post

Answer (score 1):

s only exists in the scope of the single statement:

```
'item' in s for s in mylist
```

If you want to find all items you'll have to save them first into a list. I'm not sure if you want the index of each item or the text of each item or what but you could do:

```
mylist = ['item 101', 'element 202', 'string 303', 'member 404']
items = [s for s in mylist if 'item' in s]
if any(items):
    print items[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the answer in your linked post too, and have run into the same problem. However, if you use a proper comprehension to create a list of booleans, it should work:

```
>>> mylist = ['item 101', 'element 202', 'string 303', 'member 404']
>>> if any(['item' in s for s in mylist]):
...     print 'Found item'
```

prints out what is expected.