# Difference between usage of "in" operator in strings and list containing strings in python

Tags: python

I've used "in" operator in different scenarios below. One is directly on a string and another on a list of strings.

```
>>> "yo" in "without you"
True
>>> "yo" in "without you".split()
False
```

Why is the output different?

Comment: Try `print("without you".split())`

Comment: Use [**`any`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any), if you want to see if `'yo'` is in a string in a list: `any('yo' in word for word in 'without you'.split())`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a Python list item contains a string inside another string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843158/check-if-a-python-list-item-contains-a-string-inside-another-string)

Comment: did you look at what `"without you".split()` returns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For strings, the `in` operator returns true if the left-hand-side is a *substring* of the right-hand-side.

So `"yo" in "without you"` asks: Does the substring `"yo"` appear anywhere in the string `"without you"`? Yes.

---

For sequences (like lists), the `in` operator returns true if the left-hand-side is *equal to* any element in the right-hand-side.

`"without you".split()` will return `["without", "you"]`.

So `"yo" in ["without", "you"]` asks:  Does`"yo"` equal one of those two strings? No.

---

**See also**

- [Membership test details](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) (docs.python.org)
- [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__)