# Find an entry in a list based on a partial string

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have this list:

```
item = ['AAA:60', 'BBB:10', 'CCC:65', 'DDD:70', 'EEE:70']
```

and then I get this string passed to me:

```
widget = 'BBB'
```

I'd like to find the entry in `item` based on `widget`.

I want to find the entry in the list if `widget` is contained in any of the list entries.  Something where I can use `item[i]` and preserve the list for the loop it will endure.

Final output would be the list entry itself, `BBB:10`. (In the example provided.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will be doing lots of this searching, please revisit your design. This really should be a dict where the widget name is the key and the 60, 10, 65, etc. values would be the values. You could construct this from your current list using

```
item_dict = dict((k,int(v)) for k,v in (i.rsplit(':') for i in item))
```

Then you could easily lookup values using:

```
item_dict['BBB'] # 10 (already converted to an int)
```

`in` operator now does predictable test for existence:

```
'BBB' in item_dict # True
'BB' in item_dict # False
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
>>> item = ['AAA:60', 'BBB:10', 'CCC:65', 'DDD:70', 'EEE:70']
>>> widget = 'BBB'

>>> next(i for i in item if i.startswith(widget))
'BBB:10'
```

Or if it doesn't necessarily have to begin with `"BBB"` then you can change the condition to

```
>>> next(i for i in item if widget in i)
'BBB:10'
>>> next(idx for idx,i in enumerate(item) if widget in i)
1
```

**EDIT:** Please also read [@PaulMcGuire's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37049906/2932244). In terms of design that is how it should be done.

Comment: what is my index then to item[]?  I am trying to wrap this around an `IF`

Comment: @chow - You can simply enumerate the list and fetch your result `next(idx for idx,i in enumerate(item) if widget in i)`.

Comment: What if you search for 'BB? You will get a false hit on 'BBB:10' using either `startswith` or `in` testing. Safer to test for `if i.startswith(widget+':')`. This assumes that ':' is not valid as a widget identifier - probably a safe assumption given the ':' delimiter in the item list.