# Subsetting a dataframe that contains words from a list in R

Tags: r, list, filter, subset

I have a database (let's call it "DBA") containing locations for species observations which is aprox. 32k rows long and another database ("DBB") containing aprox. 8.7k names of locations within the area of study. I need to develop a script where I create a subset ("DBC") of DBA consisting of only entries which contain any of the words listed on DBB. It should check each of the 32k rows to look for the words on the first position of DBB, then the second position and so on... It is possible that more than one entry in DBA contain the words "empire state".

That means that if there's a entry on DBB called "empire state", all rows containing these words would be included on DBC. **Ideally, this script would consier entries like "somewhere near empire state" or "empire state building". If this is not possible, an exact match of words would suffice.**

I know `subset()` would deliver me exactly what i want, if i had only one location name, such as:

```
DBA = as_tibble(read.csv("./table.csv"))

DBC = subset(DBA, DBA$locationname == "empire state")
```

However, I can't make it work on a list, and I have 8.7k names of locations, which I'm not willing to type by hand. I also tried including the `select()` function on my subset, but I received errors...

I have read answers where such problem was addressed with Python like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531482/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-an-element-from-a-list-in-python/6531704#6531704), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37042291/find-an-entry-in-a-list-based-on-a-partial-string) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380326/check-if-substring-is-in-a-list-of-strings/16381580#16381580) but **I'm trying to find a solution using R.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a vector of strings with length > 1, use `%in%`

```
vec_of_names <- c("empire state", "empire state building")
subset(DBA, locationname %in% vec_of_names)
```

Comment: This answer is helpful, but I can't type all tiny variations of 8k possible names. I want my list to have only "empire state", but when subsetting DBA, it will also select entries on DBA that have "empire state building" written on it. Meaning the content of a cell doesn't need to be an exact match.

Comment: @EricLino If you have a vector of unique substring names, you may use `grepl` as well `subset(DBA, Reduce("|", lapply(vec_substring, function(pat) grepl(pat, locationname))))`

Comment: @arkun your proposed solution worked for only one entry, then it gave the following error. "In grepl(pat, locationname) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used. Should i warp this with a for snippet, and a rbind?

Comment: @EricLino `lapply` is looping over each element of the vec_substring to be applied on grepl, then we `Reduce` to a single logical vector for subsetting

Comment: @arkun Okay, but the function suggested doesn't work. Would you like me to provide you with the data so you can assess it better?

Comment: @EricLino You can update your post with a small reproducible example using `dput` on a subset of data alogn with your expected output so that it becomes easier to test

Comment: @arkun I'm sorry, I've managed to make it work, I was missing an argument. However, now I need to exclude some words from the search. Generic words, such as "river", "forest". Where should I insert it on the code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @EricLino I didn't get your comment.  Can you show a small exampl

Comment: @arkun data is available at https://wetransfer.com/downloads/17a0bad56b6c0e07b5c9eed3074fc37320230110174355/3a61b8

At line 14 of the code, I want to insert some words that my filter can ignore, but i don't know where to insert it.