# How to check if a value in a variable in a list held in another variable

Tags: python-3.x

```
import csv

samsung = ['samsung','s1','s2','s3','s4','s5','s6','s7','galaxy']
iphone = ['iphone']
problemTypes = []
solution = []
instruction = []

def solve():
    def foundProblem():
        for queryPart in whatProblem:
            for problem in problemTypes:
                if queryPart == problem:
                    return True
    solved = False
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',') 
    for row in readCSV:
        solution = row[0] 
        problemTypes = row[1].split()
        instruction = row[2]
        if foundProblem():
            print('The solution is to '+solution)
            print(instruction)
            solved = True
    if solved == False:
        print('Solution not found.\nPlease contact your supplier')

whatProblem = str(input('What seems to be the issue with your smartphone?\n')).lower().split()
version = input('What type of phone do you have?\n').lower().split()
if version == iphone:
    with open('iPhone.csv') as csvfile:
        solve()
elif version in samsung:
    with open('samsung.csv') as csvfile:
        solve()
else:
    print('Phone not supported')
```

This is an attempt at creating a trouble shooter using multiple csv files however I am met with the problem of the samsung part. It seems that it cannot notice that the input is actually part of the samsung variable. I am new here so if I have formatted this wrong please notify me and if the solution is extremely simple please know I am new to coding.

Comment: what exactly do you need help for:?

Answer (score 0):

Try at least to change this line:

```
version = input('What type of phone do you have?\n').lower().split()
```

into:

```
version = input('What type of phone do you have?\n').lower().split()[0]
```

But reading input you currently force the user to enter 'samsung' which is not the most accessible approach. Keep on learning and trying and it will work out fine!

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear which bit you're having a problem with, but this extract looks wrong:

```
with open('iPhone.csv') as csvfile:
    solve()
```

You probably intend to use `csvfile` within the block:

```
with open('iPhone.csv') as csvfile:
    solve(csvfile)
```

and to change the implementation of `solve` to accept `csvfile` as an argument.  As it is, it looks like you're trying (and failing) to communicate via a global variable; even if that did work, it's a poor practice that leads to unmaintainable code!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your problem is either but maybe try this statement instead of your other elif statement:

```
  elif any(version in s for s in samsung):
```

[Check if a Python list item contains a string inside another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843158/check-if-a-python-list-item-contains-a-string-inside-another-string)