# Convert many line of procedure code in one line using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This is a procedure, I wanna convert it in one line:

```
def fix_machine(debris, product):
    i=0
    while(i<len(product)):
        if(debris.find(product[i]) == -1):
            return "Give me something that's not useless next time."
            break
        i = i + 1
    return product
```

Comment: Describe your problem ??

Comment: I would like to transform this code in one line... @KhairulBasarRofi

Comment: Please provide sample values for `debris` and `product`. `debris` is a string, because it has a `find`, yes? And `product` is a list of strings?

Comment: I think this question is an answer to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843158/check-if-a-python-list-item-contains-a-string-inside-another-string

Comment: **product** is a string too @MartinBurch .. don't care about the code guy !!!! I would like to get the same code in one line, this is my question ....

Comment: You've just received my first-ever down-vote since I joined SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
debris = 'widget_z'
product = ['widget_a', 'widget_b', 'widget_c', 'widget_d']

if debris not in product: print("Give me something that's not useless next time.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Better explain what `debris` and `product` is next time, but I think you want this:

```
def fix_machine(debris, product):    
    if set(product) <= set(debris):
        return product
    else:
        return "Give me something that's not useless next time."
```

I assume `debris` and `product` are both strings for now.