# Search list item in the output python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need a help,

```
 list1 = [abc, xyz]
```

output:

```
123
143
153
abc!
abc
hhj
xyz--
xyz
```

I am using below code:

```
 for line in ouput.split("\n"):
    line = line.strip()

    if (re.search(list1, line)):
        print "abc and xyz present in output"
```

Above code does not work for my requirement

Note it should not macth for abc! and xyz-- meaning it must match only abc and xyz

Comment: I don’t get what you’re trying to do, please provide a **minimal complete verifiable example**, with a sample input and the desired output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4843158/6619424

Comment: The `re.search` method should take a regular expression as its first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is pretty unclear and lacks a **mcve**. If you want to check *possession*, if `line` is the same as something inside `list1`, you can just use the `in` operator.

```
if line in list1:
    print "abc or xyz present in output"
```

In your case, it should match twice, once for `abc` and once for `xyz`. Since you said:

> Note it should not macth for abc! and xyz--

Note: regex is for searching patterns in a string. Not very appropriate for your task.

Comment: because i want match only abc and not abc! if i use above method it will match abc! as well .

Comment: No, it won’t. Have you tried it? Btw, `list1 = ["abc", "xyz"]` there’s quotes to define string

Answer (score 0):

guesing you want to search each output line is in list1 or not!
check this out you don't need regex

```
list1 = ['abc', 'xyz']
output='''123
143
153
abc!
abc
hhj
xyz--
xyz'''

for line in output.split("\n"):
    line = line.strip()
    if line in list1:
        print line,"present in output"
```

output:

> abc present in output
>   xyz present in output

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use regex you can use this:

```
import re

output = """123
143
153
abc!
abc
hhj
xyz--
xyz"""

print(output)

for line in output.split("\n"):
    line = line.strip()
        if re.search(r"^\babc\b$", line) or re.search(r"^\bxyz\b$", line):
        print('line matched: {}'.format(line))
```

However, I would create a separate dictionary and look for the matches in there:

```
keywords = {'abc' : 0, 'xyz' :0, ...}

for line in output.split("\n"):
    if line in keywords:
        print('line matched: {}'.format(line))
```

Dictionary makes sense if you have a lot of keywords and they are all unique and your `output` file contains a lot of lines. The lookup time will be constant O(1).

If you use list of keywords the lookup will be O(n) which in total make your algorithm O(n^2).