# for any item of list1 if it is list2 in python

Tags: python

[Check if a Python list item contains a string inside another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843158/check-if-a-python-list-item-contains-a-string-inside-another-string)
according to this question and in first answer, instead of a string , I want to loop in list

I have tried this but it didn't work

```
matching = [s for s in fd if [s for s in chht] in fd]
```

for more declare

I have list 1=["he","bell","go"]
list=["o","e"]

so the actual output is :

words has o letter are ["go"]

words has e letter are ["he","bell"]

Comment: Why does it not work? Please show some example input and expected/actual result.

Comment: The code itself is not complete

Comment: I update my question, read it again

Answer (score 0):

Try using `any`:

```
matching = any([s in chht for s in fd])
```

Comment: I dont know but it returned on false 

look for declare 

I have list 1=["he","bell","go"]
list=["o","e"]

so the actual output is 

words has o letter are ["go"]

words has e letter are ["he","bell"]

Answer (score 0):

```py
wordList = ["he", "bell", "go"]
searchCharList = ["o", "e"]
matching = [word for word in wordList for char in searchCharList if char in word]

print matching
>>> ['he', 'bell', 'go']

print bool(matching)
>>> True
```

Comment: Thanks worked for me

I want to upvote but this notice came to me

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.