# Extract "root" from list in list in Python

Tags: python, list, nlp, nltk

Edit: the solution is: there is a label() function! So I just need to find the sublist for which sublist.label() == SBAR.

I have a list that looks like this

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP
      (NP (DT The) (NN dog))
      (SBAR
        (WHNP (WP who))
        (S (VP (VBD ate) (NP (DT the) (NN food))))))
    (VP (VBZ is) (ADJP (JJ dead)))
    (. .)))
```

edit: I can also have this output, if this makes it easier:

```
[Tree('S', [Tree('NP', [Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['The']), Tree('NN', ['play'])]), Tree(',', [',']), Tree('SBAR', [Tree('WHNP', [Tree('WDT', ['which'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('VP', [Tree('VBD', ['started']), Tree('NP-TMP', [Tree('JJ', ['last']), Tree('NN', ['week'])])])])]), Tree(',', [','])]), Tree('VP', [Tree('VBZ', ['has']), Tree('VP', [Tree('VBN', ['been']), Tree('VP', [Tree('VBN', ['sold']), Tree('PRT', [Tree('RP', ['out'])]), Tree('ADVP', [Tree('RB', ['ever'])]), Tree('ADVP', [Tree('IN', ['since'])])])])]), Tree('.', ['.'])])]
```

and I want to search for the sublist

```
(SBAR
        (WHNP (WP who))
        (S (VP (VBD ate) (NP (DT the) (NN food))))))
```

However, I don't know how to find the list with the "root" SBAR. 
When I code this

```
print(parse[0][0][1][0])
print(parse[0][0][1][1])
```

I get

```
------0010------
(WHNP (WP who))
------0011------
(S (VP (VBD ate) (NP (DT the) (NN food))))
```

How can I search for SBAR? Or in other words, how can I write a loop that access the list that has the "root" SBAR?

Thanks!

Edit:
here's my code

```
STANFORD = os.path.abspath("stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05")

# Create the server
server = CoreNLPServer(
   os.path.join(STANFORD, "stanford-corenlp-3.9.2.jar"),
   os.path.join(STANFORD, "stanford-corenlp-3.9.2-models.jar"),    
)

# Start the server in the background
server.start()

parser = CoreNLPParser()
parse = next(parser.raw_parse(sentence))

print(parse[0][0][1][0])
print(parse[0][0][1][1])

server.stop()
```

I don't know if that helps a lot... What I get is a (nested?) list

Thanks again

Comment: your list example is not "pythonic". I find it hard to understand the question, try the following link maybe it will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843158/check-if-a-python-list-item-contains-a-string-inside-another-string

Comment: Thanks! I'm working with the Stanford Parser, maybe this is why my list is not "pythonic"?  Thanks for the link. Do you know how I could know where "SBAR" is? I need the whole sub-list...

Comment: For get best solution, you should **submit the code** you wrote... it is hard to understand if your output is a String or a List or nested list? ```list = ["(ROOT",   " (S", "(NP", <every line is string>]```

Comment: I added my code. I checked for isinstance(parse,list) and the ouput is TRUE