# Is there any way to get the name of a list once a string within has been searched for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

First of all, complete python/programming newbie here, so I apologise if this is a stupid question. Also, sorry for the awkward title.

I'm attempting to adapt the top answer in this question:
[Check if a Python list item contains a string inside another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843158/check-if-a-python-list-item-contains-a-string-inside-another-string). However, I'm not sure if what I'm trying to achieve is even possible.

```
list6 = [list1,list2,list3,list4,list5]
```

'list6' is a list containing several other lists.
Then, this line can be used to check if 'Cool' is a string inside of any of those lists:

```
if any("Cool" in s for s in list6):
```

My question is: Assuming 'Cool' is only in 'list1', is it possible to fetch and store 'list1' in order to use other values within that list? For example:

```
if "Cool" is in any list in list6:
    list = list with "Cool"
    something = list[4]
```

Comment: you would have to use `for`-loop to check every sublist separatelly and then you can keep it and get other elements from this sublist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with a generator expression (Thanks ShadowRanger)

```
next(sublist for sublist in list6 if "Cool" in sublist)
```

or you can use next with an iterator such as [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to get the first item that contains the element

```
next(filter(lambda x: "Cool" in x, list6))
```

Comment: Slightly nicer than `filter`+`lambda` is a simple genexpr: `next(sublist for sublist in list6 if "Cool" in sublist)`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - Thanks! I was trying to use just next but been awake for far too long today it seems

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use `for`-loop to check every sublist separatelly and then you can keep it or get other elements from this sublist.

```
for sublist in list6:
    if "Cool" in sublist:
        something = sublist[4]
```

Comment: Note: Add a `break` inside the `if` unless you want to keep looking after you've already got a hit to get the last hit (and if you did want to keep the last hit, you'd be better off looping over `reversed(list6)` and still `break`ing when you get a hit).