# Pandas dafaframe, how to use iloc value in a variable

Tags: pandas, dataframe, variables

I'm working with a dataframe.
How come this filter function returns nothing, not even an error?

```
print(df.iloc[0,4])

==> a

def filter(x):
   if x in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
       print("yes")

var = df.iloc[0,4]

filter(var)
```

==> nothing

Comment: If var is not in ['a', 'b', 'c'] nothing will happen, as there is no action specified when the if condition is False.

Comment: is there a white space you don't see in the result of the first print?

Comment: thanks for your help. You put me on the right track. Answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843158/check-if-a-python-list-item-contains-a-string-inside-another-string