# What is the efficient way to check a present of a string in a single element list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a single element list like below

```
listx=['Digital Operations']
```

My goal is to just check if the word 'Digital' is present in the list listx

I wrote the below code

```
if any('Digital') in listx:
  print("the word digital is present")
else:
  print("word Digital not found")
```

I am getting the output "word Digital not found" despite it being clearly there. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: just `if in` for you `if 'Digital' in listx`

Comment: @BearBrown No, `'Digital'` is not in `listx`, it's in *an element* of `listx`, so you need to loop over `listx`

Comment: @wjandrea thank you. Hope the down vote is removed if no other duplicates are found.

Comment: Duplicate: [Check if a Python list item contains a string inside another string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4843158/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea my question was about single element list, the link provides a case of multiple elements in a list. I believe there is a subtle difference and hence not duplicate. Anyways I am ok if you deem it as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
listx=['Digital Operations']

if 'Digital' in listx[0]:
    print("the word digital is present")
else:
    print("word Digital not found")
```

Output:-

```
the word digital is present
```

Answer (score 2):

the `any()` function takes an iterable (for example a list) and returns `True` if any of its values is `True`. You are calling it with a `str` wich will evaluate to `True` So basically your if statement then says

```py
if True in listx:
```

which will in turn evaluate to `False`, causing your problem.

If you would like to use `any()` you could use a list comprehension like this:

```py
listx = ['Digital Operations']

listy = ['Digital' in elem for elem in listx]
if any(listy):
  print("the word digital is present")
else:
  print("word Digital not found")
```

For a more efficent version you can use a generator expression that replaces the need for `listy` and combines it into the `if`-statement like this:

```py
if any('Digital' in elem for elem in listx):
```

*thank's to wjandrea comment*

Comment: You can make this more efficient by using a generator expression instead of a list: `any('Digital' in elem for elem in listx)`. Though for a single element list it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

`any()` checks for `True` values, so if you change your first line to

```
if any(any([x=='Digital' for x in y.split()]) for y in listx):
```

You should be fine.

Comment: The last version does work, @wjandrea, but you are right, I did not run it before.

Comment: OK, it works now, but could be simplified to `any(x=='Digital' for y in listx for x in y.split())`