# How do I find predefined words in a wall of text?

Tags: python

I am thinking of an idea that I want to do for my ownself project during this quarantine phase . I am learning python by myself so I thought maybe I could see what I can do.

Question: I want to decipher large, but irregular count text and I want to find words in them, think of it like finding words. I may know the words that I find.

For example, I want to find

```
fruits = ["banana", "apples", "oranges"]
```

in

```
Text = "sdasfdsfdscbananassafdfdsafscdfbfnhujuyjhtrgrfeaddaDWEAFSERGRapplesfsgrgvscfaefcwecfrvtbhytofsdasrangesdaeubfuenijnzcjbvnkMDLOwkdpoaDPOSKPKFEOFJsfjuf"
```

How could I do that?

Also its my 1st time posting here so I am not really confident about this community.

sorry & thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO! [tour] is a great place to start!

Comment: Check out the the 'for' statement and the 'in' operator. With those two, you could do this in 3 lines of code. Bonus points if you look up list comprehensions, you could pull it off in one!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a Python list item contains a string inside another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843158/check-if-a-python-list-item-contains-a-string-inside-another-string)

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the words you want to find and check if they're in your text

```
for fruit in fruits:
    if fruit in Text:
        print(f"Found {fruit}")
```

Or, using a list comprehension:

```
found = [fruit for fruit in fruits if fruit in Text]
print(found)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
fruits = ["banana", "apples", "oranges"]
text = "sdasfdsfdscbananassafdfdsafscdfbfnhujuyjhtrgrfeaddaDWEAFSERGRapplesfsgrgvscfaefcwecfrvtbhytofsdasrangesdaeubfuenijnzcjbvnkMDLOwkdpoaDPOSKPKFEOFJsfjuf"

for fruit in fruits:
    if fruit in text: 
        print(fruit, "True") 
    else:
        print(fruit, "False")
```