# Find items in one list that do not start with an item in another list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to write a code that finds every instance in one list that does not start with an item in another list

I'm trying this:

```
list1 = ['1234', '2345', '3456', '4567']
list2 = ['1', '2']

for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        if not x.startswith(y):
            print(x)
```

but it returns this:

```
1234
2345
3456
3456
4567
4567
```

Which is baffling to me because if I remove "not" it can find items in list1 that start with an item in list2 just fine. How can I write a code that accomplishes my goal?

Comment: I suggest using debugger and running your code step-by-step.  Basically, you need to know the difference between `all` and `any`.

Comment: @ACan There are 6 output for 4 input, how is it possible? The answer to this question is your solution.

Comment: Related: [Check if a Python list item contains a string inside another string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4843158/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a purely logical problem. I'm not sure how to describe it clearly in English, so here's a table instead. Every `True` in the last column means that `x` will be printed in your code. I hope it clarifies how your code works.

```
for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        print(x, y, not x.startswith(y))
```

```
1234 1 False
1234 2 True
2345 1 True
2345 2 False
3456 1 True
3456 2 True
4567 1 True
4567 2 True
```

The solution is to loop over `list2` altogether and check the result using [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) or [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
for x in list1:
    if not any(x.startswith(y) for y in list2):
        print(x)
```

```
3456
4567
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

```
list1 = ['1234', '2345', '3456', '4567'] 
list2 = ['1', '2']
print( *[x for x in list1 if all([x[:len(l)]!=l for l in list2])],sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your code prints the output if the value not start with either 1 or 2

Try this:

```
list1 = ['1234', '2345', '3456', '4567'] 
list2 = ['1', '2'] 
for x in list1:
    if not any([x.startswith(y) for y in list2]):
            print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a for/else loop. The else will only execute if the loop isn't broken.

```
list1 = ['1234', '2345', '3456', '4567']
list2 = ['1', '2']

for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        if x.startswith(y):
            break
    else:
        print(x)
```