# How to find a substring in a string list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, search

I try to find some string in a list, but have problems because of word order.

```
list = ['a b c d', 'e f g', 'h i j k']
str = 'e g'
```

I need to find the 2nd item in a list and output it.

Comment: can you provide the code where you have tried  to solve the problem and facing error ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a Python list item contains a string inside another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843158/check-if-a-python-list-item-contains-a-string-inside-another-string)

Comment: do not use `list`, `str` or any other name which shadow built-in functions

Comment: `[i for i in l if all(c in i for c in s.split())]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use combination of `any()` and `all()` **to check the presence** in one line:

```
>>> my_list = ['a b c d', 'e f g', 'h i j k']
>>> my_str = 'e g'

>>> any(all(s in sub_list for s in my_str.split()) for sub_list in my_list)
True
```

Here, above expression will return `True` / `False` depending on whether the char in your strings are present inside the list.

To also **get the get that sub-list as return value**, you can modify above expression by skipping `any()` with *list comprehension* as:

```
>>> [sub_list for sub_list in my_list if all(s in sub_list for s in my_str.split())]
['e f g']
```

It'll return the list of strings containing your chars.

Comment: Thank you very much! Will this work with words instead of characters(in string)?

Comment: It'll work but upto certain extent, it won't be doing exact word match. For example: check for `"est"` in `"test string"` will return `True`. If you are looking for exact match of word, then it'll be better fit as a separate question. Logic of word lookup will be little different that char lookup we have here

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
for l in list:
     l_words = l.split(" ")
     if all([x in l_words for x in str.split(" ")]):
         print(l_words)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
list = ['a b c d', 'e f g', 'h i j k']
str = list[2].split()
for letter in str:
  print(letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using sets and list comprehension

```
ls = ['a b c d', 'e f g', 'h i j k']
s = 'e g'
print([i for i in ls if len(set(s.replace(" ", "")).intersection(set(i.replace(" ", "")))) == len(s.replace(" ", ""))])
```

OR

```
ls = ['a b c d', 'e f g', 'h i j k']
s = 'e g'
s_set = set(s.replace(" ", ""))
print([i for i in ls if len(s_set.intersection(set(i.replace(" ", "")))) == len(s_set)])
```

Output

```
['e f g']
```

The list comprehension is removing all the items in `ls` that all the chars from `s` are not including inside the list item, by that you will get all the `ls` items that all the `s` chars are in them.