# How to use wildcard keywords to filter a Python list?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I followed the solution in this question: [Check if a Python list item contains a string inside another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843158/check-if-a-python-list-item-contains-a-string-inside-another-string)
but the difference is I used a wildcard filter `*txt.gz`

so I have a list of file names, and I only want to return the list with `*txt.gz`

```
file_list = ['file0.test.json.gz', 'file2.txt', 'file3.test.txt.gz', 'file4.test.txt.gz']
```

Expected result:

```
['file3.test.txt.gz', 'file4.test.txt.gz']
```

I tried:

```
filtered_list = [s for s in ftp_file_list if "*txt.gz" in s]
```

output:

```
[]
```

Might someone be able to help please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `split()` and compare the last two words with `txt` and `gz`:

```
out = [file for file in file_list if file.split('.')[-1] == "gz" and file.split('.')[-2] == "txt"]
```