# How to print a specific string containing a particular word - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to print out the entire string if it contains a particular word. for example

```
a = ['www.facbook.com/xyz','www.google.com/xyz','www.amazon.com/xyz','www.instagram.com/xyz']
```

if I am looking to find the word `amazon` then the code should print `www.amazon.com/xyz`

I have found many examples in which you can find out if a string contains a word but I need to print out the entire string which contains the word.

Comment: If you have found a way to find out if a string contains a word or not, you can just use this information and access the processed entry in the list and print it then ;-)

`for entry in a: if EntryContainsWord(entry, 'word'): print(entry)`

(Sorry for the bad formatting ;-) )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a Python list item contains a string inside another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843158/check-if-a-python-list-item-contains-a-string-inside-another-string)

Comment: @GauravVerma Feel free to accept an answer if you found it helpful. (Click on the grey checkmark next to the post).

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
your_list = ['www.facebook.com/xyz', 'www.google.com/xyz', 'www.amazon.com/xyz', 'www.instagram.com/xyz']
word = 'amazon'
res = [x for x in your_list if word in x] 
print (*res)
```

Output:

```
www.amazon.com/xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine if there are only one or two strings containing the word, if there are multiple strings in the list containing that name it will print them in a horizontal line.
It needs to print line by separate line but I do not know how to incorporate this in the code. It would be interesting to see how that looks.

Comment: This should not be added as an answer, but as a comment