# How check if my string has any word who contains an element

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list:

```
my_list = ['hello', 'def-456', 'ghello', 'abc', 'helloajisjioj']
```

and want to search for items that contain the string 'hello'. How can I do that?

The result should be:
`'hello', 'ghello', 'helloajisjioj'`

How can i do that? I tried the find, but he only find 'hello'.

i tried something like:

```
if 'hello' in my_list:
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: This is literally the same question as [Check if a Python list item contains a string inside another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843158/check-if-a-python-list-item-contains-a-string-inside-another-string), including some examples and the failed attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one liner

```
print([x for x in my_list if "hello" in x])
```

Output:

```
['hello', 'ghello', 'helloajisjioj']
```

Comment: Thank you, it fuctions, but i don't understand de x for x in my_list? is it a double for loop?

Comment: That is list comprehension. it means: ```a=[]```, ```for x in my_list:```, ```if hello in x: ```, ```a.append(x)```, ```print(a)``` @guiguilecodeur

Comment: It's simpler to point to the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, but the nices is probably with list comprehension:

```
words_with_hello = [word for word in my_list if "hello" in word]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `filter`

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: 'hello' in x, my_list))
['hello', 'ghello', 'helloajisjioj']
```

Comment: Good variation, but it's worth mentioning that list comprehension is faster and more "pythonic".

Comment: Good point. I just wanted to point that such feature exists.