# How to test for substrings in the list

Tags: python, string, list

I need to check if a string is in the list `my_list`.

```
my_list = ['word1,word2,word3', 'g1,g2', 'word1']
```

When I run `'word2' in my_list`, it returns False instead of True.

How can I test for substrings in the list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a string is a substring of items in a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843158/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-substring-of-items-in-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: or maybe this one? [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check whether your string is part of each list *element*.

Something like this:

```
for elem in my_list:
    if 'word_2' in elem: return True
```